# Nopagebreak nopagebreak nopagebreak - why won't LaTeX listen to me?

Tags: page-breaking

Fun times, I'm making a (manual) index of the lecture slides for class (which are nowhere near latex, ppt files yay) and of course Latex insists on placing pagebreaks willie nillie through my items. Why isn't there a "keep (paragraph) with next (paragraph)" option like there is in Word 2007 (and all others I think). Is Word really more powerful than Latex [when it comes to this specific attribute of paragraph flow]?

```
*full page before here*
Knowledge in the \nopagebreak\\
\nopagebreak
\nopagebreak - Head
```

Results in

```
*full page*
Knowledge in the 
---8<--- Next page
- Head ...
```

Yes, I know I can place a `\newpage` before the line to push it to the next page, but there has to [HAS TO] be a way to make Latex understand that this isn't what I want, these two lines are supposed to stick together!

Edit: Full context:

```
*empty line*
Knowledge in the \\
- Head \slid{44, 69}
- World \slid{5, \textbf{44}, 66, 69, 84}
*empty line*
```

With slid being:

```
\newcommand{\slid}[1]{\dotfill #1 \nopagebreak\\}
```

It seems to be to be that the -World line is pulling down the -Head line, if I add an empty line between them, both Knowledge.. and -Head stay on the same page, with -World on the next one. But when I combine the two, only -Head gets pulled to a new page, and Knowledge... stays on the previous page.

Comment: Yes, `\nopagebreak` can be extremely tricky, and this is unfortunate. While this site is the right place to ask such a question, I think it's not a place to rant about LaTeX.

Comment: what would you suggest I change to reduce the "rant" to a "colorful commentary"?

Comment: @gakera: Try to go into a bikers bar and rant about bikes. ;-)

Comment: @Stefan It's the Word comment, isn't it :) I knew that would get under some skins, people have to have a sense of humor also, this is harmless teasing. And, if this is truly something that Word can do but Latex can not do, I stand by my "rant", hah! :D

Comment: @gakera: Depends on what you mean by "colorful", but "reduce" sounds good. (For example in your [comments here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5573/1235), I also felt that you were ranting, and I found it unpleasant.)

Comment: @gakera: and not only is this not a place to rant about LaTeX, even more so it's not a place to try and get under other people's skins. (_Humor_ is appreciated!)

Comment: I have a tendency to rant when it comes to Latex, mainly because of weird things like these. And I try to keep it just, as I said, if this is truly something that is easier to do in Word than in Latex, I don't feel I overstepped anything. I'm sorry if you find my critique of Latex unpleasant, but it wouldn't be what it is today if nobody critiqued it.

Comment: There, I added better context to my juxtaposition, now I feel it is completely just! :)

Comment: @gakera: Now you have added some context, that's good. However, I can't reproduce the behaviour you're describing: For me, `\nopagebreak` does work. Maybe you can replace the context bit with a full compilable (but minimal) example? (Incidentally, I'm a professional when it comes to ranting; I even rant about LaTeX from time to time. I just don't do it here as I like the site to be a friendly place.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If "- Head -" is a normal text line `\\*` should work. If not we need to know what it is. In a lot of case solutions with `\@afterheading` can be used, e.g.:

```
\makeatletter 
\def\mynobreakpar{\par\nobreak\@afterheading} 
\def\mynobreakline{\par\nobreak\vspace{-\parskip}\@afterheading\noindent} 
\makeatother
```

Comment: OOOHH, I had such high hopes for `\\\*` I'm sad to say that doesn't change anything, but I did update the OP with full context, to me the -Head line is just a normal text line, unless I'm just way too stupid to be using Latex.

Comment: Ah, I see. Your `\\*` is after the first line of a paragraph. In this case `\clubpenalty` gets in the way. You will have to set it to 10000 temporarly for this paragraph. (`\clubpenalty=10000`).

Comment: AHA! \clubpenalty=10000 added after the `\\\*` in the Knowledge ... line works great! Thanks.

Answer (score 36):

You could use a `minipage` environment or a `\parbox`. They won't be broken accross pages.

Further, LaTeX provides the `\samepage` command, which may be used as environment: `\begin{samepage}...\end{samepage}`. But I would not use `samepage` because it relies on setting penalties.

Also, the [`needspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace) packages comes often handy in such cases.

Comment: hmm needspace sounds interesting. I decided to use \begin{minipage}{\textwidth} ... \end{minipage} even though that feels like I'm shooting a canon at the canary.

Comment: out of curiosity, what's wrong with setting penalties?  Isn't that the proper TeX way of influencing breaks?

Comment: @Jan: It might not work at all places. And `\samepage` support is questionable in LaTeX2e, which can be read in source2e.pdf p344, p358.

Comment: A downside of `\samepage`is that `\marginpar` text seems to become unusable inside that block.

Comment: An example of minipage might be nice to add to your answer: `\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}...\end{minipage}`

Comment: For `minipage` you should use `\linewidth` as parameter, so it works in environments (like `enumerate`) too (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16942/123129)).

Answer (score 13):

You could also do this with samepage:

```
*full page before here*
\begin{samepage}
Knowledge in the \\

- Head
\end{samepage}
```

Answer (score 10):

Alternately, use the [`needspace`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/needspace) package. Before entering a bit where you absolutely need to have 48 points of vertical space (for example) put in `\needspace{48pt}`

Answer (score 8):

Did you try `\nopagebreak[4]` ? As to the second part of your question

> Is Word really more powerful than
>   Latex?

There is absolutely no comparison to LaTeX. Word produces ugly, unstructured documents, crashes frequently, can eat your files and you have to `recover`, knows of no typographical rules and you have to pay a `licence`. As opposed to LaTeX it processes words rather than typesetting books, articles or other structured documents.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `\nopagebreak[4]` is equivalent to `\nopagebreak`.

Comment: Yes, same results with all those nopagebreaks turned up to 4 :(   I know Word sucks, but at least this is no problem to do in Word. Just one click and all is well.

Comment: @Hendrik possibly it can still fail in a bad spot, 0 : penalty = 0,
1 : penalty = \@lowpenalty, 2 : penalty = \@medpenalty, 3 : penalty = \@highpenalty, 4 : penalty = 10000, but without a minimal is difficult to check.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're aiming at. Of course `\nopagebreak` can fail, but adding `[4]` doesn't help as indeed those two are equivalent.

Comment: :-( I have to disagree with nearly everything you said about Word (or any comparable open source alternative). I think LaTeX is uglier (less consistent), harder to use, crashes more (or worse, fails to compile/create the document at all)...  Yes LaTeX is more powerful, but it's also far more crude. I don't need to build a combustion engine every time I want to drive to the store, I shouldn't have to build an entire typesetting structure every time I want to write a paper. It's just horrific.