# Difference between \textwidth, \linewidth and \hsize

Tags: margins, lengths

The three lengths `\textwidth`, `\linewidth` and `\hsize` seem to all hold the width of the current line. At least I never saw some real difference between `\textwidth` and `\linewidth` in my code. Both seem to be identical even when changed, e.g. by a `minipage` environment.

Could someone give me an elaborate explanation of the differences between these lengths? I like to understand them in detail. I know that the first two are from LaTeX and the latter one from plainTeX.

There is also `\columnwidth` which seems to be identical to `\linewidth` or `\textwidth` in one-column mode, right? Except when the line is reduced by a `minipage` or `quote` etc. environment.

Comment: In addition to the other helpful answers, a useful list with several lengths:
[LaTeX default lengths](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths#LaTeX_default_lengths)

Answer (score 342, accepted):

`\hsize` is the main parameter that TeX uses when typesetting: whenever it finishes a paragraph it looks at the current value of `\hsize` for breaking it into horizontal boxes. Next, there are `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` and possibly other paragraph shape parameters (`\hangindent` and `\hangafter` or the more general `\parshape`).

LaTeX uses an indirect approach and maintains many `\...width` parameters.

`\textwidth` is generally the global width of the text area, while `\columnwidth` is the width of a column of text (it will be different from `\textwidth` when typesetting in two or more columns). However, inside a `minipage`, `\textwidth` will be set to the given argument along with `\hsize`, `\columnwidth`, and `\linewidth` (they will revert to the previous values at the end of the `minipage` because it forms a group). Note that `\parbox` doesn't reset `\textwidth`; the size is available as `\linewidth`.

The parameter `\linewidth` contains the line length inside a `list` (or derived) environment and it may change in a nested list (while `\hsize`, `\textwidth` and `\columnwidth` don't change).

When we have to specify a length depending on current conditions, we have to use the correct parameter. For example, the width of a figure should be specified in terms of `\columnwidth` in a `figure` environment and of `\textwidth` in a `figure*` environment; however this is done rarely when it's known that the document will be typeset in one column format. The same should be for a `tabular*` or `tabularx` environment.

Instead, when we need something centered with respect to a line in a `list`, we should use `\linewidth`:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item some text that contains a `here' table
      \begin{center}
      \begin{tabularx}{.9\linewidth}{lXX}
      ...
      \end{tabularx}
      \end{center}
      and some other text that follows.
\item ...
\end{enumerate}
```

In this case it would be wrong to use `\textwidth` or `\columnwidth`, as the line length is "unknown" at typing time.

Notice that LaTeX uses `\hangindent` only for typesetting sectional titles and `\leftskip` and `rightskip` for `\centering`, `\raggedright` and `\raggedleft`; the indentation of a `list` environment is obtained via `\parshape`.

Comment: Couldn't the general advice for the width of the figure be to always use \linewidth?

Comment: I.e., the way that I think about it is that `\linewidth` is the most general of the lot, adapting to its current situation, whereas `\textwidth` and `\columnwidth` are fixed design-oriented lengths. (And `\hsize` should be avoided in LaTeX, generally speaking.)

Comment: @Will: there's the problem that we don't know *a priori* the value of `\linewidth` that will be used. For example, writing a `\begin{figure}[h]` environment in the middle of a list and using `\linewidth` will probably give a surprise.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. A figure is always set full-width; I'm not sure if you'd ever consider it ‘proper’ to put a figure inside a list like this and expect `\linewidth` to respect the list sizing. It seems fairly ludicrous to have a captioned figure *as part of* a list, don't you think?

Comment: @Will: I am actually putting figures (from standalone files) within an enumerated list. The same figure is used in different contexts and in one they happen to be part of a list.

Comment: @egreg: If I want to change `\hsize` in a group, should I then use `\par\begingroup\hsize=<new value> ... \par\endgroup` or swap the `\par` with the `\begingroup` (or the second one with the `\endgroup`).

Comment: @Martin: this is the correct way. Exchanging the first two tokens is quite the same (if `\par` is primitive `\par`), while exchanging the last two is disastrous.

Comment: @egreg Inside a `\parbox` `\textwidth` will not be set to the width of the this box.

Comment: @egreg Are the values of `\hsize` and `\columnwidth` always the same?

Comment: @Kun No, they aren't

Answer (score 177):

I think the simplest way to describe the difference is as follows:

- `\hsize` is a TeX primitive that should not be usually used in LaTeX
- `\textwidth` is the (constant) width of the total text block
- `\columnwidth` is the (constant) width of a single column of text
  (which is the same as `\textwidth` for a single column document)
- `\linewidth` is a variable that represents the *current* size of the line of text, whether inside a column or a minipage or a list

In general, then, it's best to always use `\linewidth` if you are specifying the relative size of an image or a box, since it will adapt to the current situation.

**Note**: `\linewidth` also appears to work in *table* columns, not just text columns. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78296/13270) for an example where a fixed-width parbox is used within a table cell (actually a multirow cell).

Answer (score 62):

A test document in a `twocolumn` and `onecolumn`mode:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage[paperheight=7cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\leavevmode\rlap{text:}\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\par
\leavevmode\rlap{line:}\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}\par
\leavevmode\rlap{hsize:}\rule{\hsize}{2pt}\par
\leavevmode\rlap{column:}\rule{\columnwidth}{2pt}

\begin{itemize}
\item \rule{\textwidth}{5pt}
\item \rule{\linewidth}{5pt}
\item \rule{\hsize}{5pt}
\item \rule{\columnwidth}{5pt}
\end{itemize}

\onecolumn
\leavevmode\rlap{text:}\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\par
\leavevmode\rlap{line:}\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}\par
\leavevmode\rlap{hsize:}\rule{\hsize}{2pt}\par
\leavevmode\rlap{column:}\rule{\columnwidth}{2pt}

\begin{itemize}
\item \rule{\textwidth}{5pt}
\item \rule{\linewidth}{5pt}
\item \rule{\hsize}{5pt}
\item \rule{\columnwidth}{5pt}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Herbert, but it would be really nice to have some general explanation for this lengths, for one- and two-column mode.

Answer (score 11):

One difference is that in list and trivlist environments (i.e., including `quote`, `quotation`, and other such environments), `\linewidth` is smaller than `\textwidth` by the sum of `\leftmargin` and `\rightmargin`.  I think I also remember that `\hsize` is what's used by the routine that breaks paragraphs into lines; since `\leftmargin` in a list is created by using the `\parshape` command, that routine doesn't need to be explicitly told about `\leftmargin`.