# How to center the minipage?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage

The left margin is too wide if I set `1.5\textwidth`:

```
\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{1.5\textwidth}

test

\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Put it inside a centered box

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent\hrulefill\par
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{%
    \begin{minipage}{1.5\textwidth}
        \hrulefill\par
    \end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think `\linewidth` should be used instead of `\textwidth` per [this post about the difference between these two](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/difference-between-textwidth-linewidth-and-hsize)

Comment: @Peter Grill: The OP asked for `\textwidth` and it is difficult to say without context what it is used for. If you are looking for a fixed global width it is `\textwidth`. If the widths need to change with local column, environment of box width, then use `\linewidth`

Comment: This response not works fine for `msupertabular` environment.

Comment: This doesn't quite work if you put two minipages in it.

Comment: It worked for my case with three minipages. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

A simple way to do this is to use `\centerline{..}` around the `minipage`. (This does not allow for verbatim or similar special content, but there is a `\Centerline` variant from the `realboxes` package, which does!)

I would add some small or medium vertical skip before and after this `minipage` to get decent vertical spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\par\smallskip\noindent
\centerline{\begin{minipage}{1.5\textwidth}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}}
\par\smallskip

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Another easy way is to use the `adjustbox` environment from the package with the same name. It provides the keys `minipage=<minipage args>`, `center`(`=<length>`, normally `\linewidth`) and also `margin`(`=<left/right> <top/bottom>`, and more).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=1.5\textwidth,margin=0pt \smallskipamount,center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{adjustbox}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Compare the similar question and answers at [How can I center a too wide table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39435/how-can-i-center-a-too-wide-table/39436#39436).

Comment: It should be noted that using `\centerline` is deprecated in LaTeX (at least according to the [l2tabu](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf) document).

Comment: @mhp: Thanks, I was not aware of that. I find it very useful from time to time. Looking at `l2tabu` it stated that it should not be used to center text, because it e.g. can cause issues when used inside lists. I think it is fine for this case, i.e. a large block in a paragraph of it's own.

Answer (score 5):

I was putting parcolumns and verbatim blocks inside my minipage which was causing problems. I found this rather simple solution quite effective:

```
\noindent\hspace{0.15\linewidth}\begin{minipage}{0.7\linewidth}
...
\end{minipage}
```

This creates a smaller minipage and centres with a positive hspace. Using the rule `hspace = (1\linewidth - minipage_width) / 2` will also work for values larger than `\linewidth` and produce a negative hspace:

```
\newlength{\myminipagewidth}
\newlength{\myminipagecentering}
\setlength{\myminipagewidth}{1.5\linewidth} %change this
\setlength{\myminipagecentering}{(\linewidth-\myminipagewidth)/2}
\noindent\hspace{\myminipagecentering}\begin{minipage}{\myminipagewidth}
...
\end{minipage}
```

(sub `\linewidth` with `\textwidth` when needed)

Answer (score -1):

Very simple, enclose that minipage in center using \begin{center} and \end{center} as shown below:

```
\begin{center}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{1.5\textwidth}

text

\end{minipage}

\end{center}
```

Comment: The `center` environment will not center content that is wider than the textwidth. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}

\begin{minipage}{1.5\textwidth}
\lipsum[4]
\end{minipage}

\end{center}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}` will result in https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdtEI.png

Comment: Still, it remains useful in more "regular", simpler cases.