# How can I center a too wide table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have a document containing a table which is slightly too wide for the page. But instead of growing to the right side only, I would like to have it centered on the page.

I have tried to use the `center` environment but this doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Have a look at [Center flow chart horizontally](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2319/center-flow-chart-horizontally), the answer works also for too wide tables, perhaps also have a look at [Centering wide tables or figures](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/centering-figure-table/). Similar solution here: [How to center the minipage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18496/how-to-center-the-minipage).

Comment: Please compose a compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I don't think a MWE is really necessary here. It's kind of a common, easily understandable issue.

Comment: @martin  Sure, but knowing, say, the class, help know which tools are readily available.

Comment: See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32726/center-wide-longtable-not-tabular-or-tabularx

Comment: @DevSolar In the second column there will be emails and in the las columnn there will be brief descriptions of tasks, which requires wide columns.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

If a table (or any other horizontal box) is wider than the text (`\textwidth`) an *overfull hbox* warning is given and the content is placed anyway, which makes it run into the right margin. To avoid this and to suppress the error the content must be placed in a box with is equal or smaller than `\textwidth`. The `\makebox` macro with its two optional argument for the width and horizontal alignment can be used for this: `\makebox[\textwidth][c]{<table>}`  will center the content. See [Center figure that is wider than \textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth) and [Place figures side by side, spill into outer margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/place-figures-side-by-side-spill-into-outer-margin/10507#10507) were this is used for figures and further explained.

For more complicated tables, especially if they should contain verbatim material, you should use a different approach. `\makebox` reads the whole content as macro argument which does not allow verbatim content and is not very efficient (ok, nowadays the latter isn't really important any longer). The `\Makebox` macro or the `Makebox` environment from the `realboxes` can be used as an replacement. It reads the content as a box. Better would be the `adjustbox` macro or environment from the `adjustbox` package together with the `center` key.

```
\begin{adjustbox}{center}
<your table (i.e. the tabular or similar environment)>
\end{adjustbox}
```

Which centers the content to `\linewidth` (mostly identical to `\textwidth`) by default but also takes any other length as an optional value, e.g. `center=10cm`. Note that `<your table>` should be a `tabular` or equivalent environment, not a `table` environment.

---

You can now also use the `tabular` key of `adjustbox` (as first key!) to save the extra `\begin{tabular}` .. `\end{tabular}` which is then added internally.

```
\begin{adjustbox}{tabular=lll,center}
     a & b & c \\
     a & b & c \\
     a & b & c \\
\end{adjustbox}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. Why not use \centerline{} as suggested in another answer? Are you aware of any drawbacks?

Comment: @Dejan: `\centerline` reads the content as a macro argument as well and is basically the same as `\makebox[\hsize][c]`, using more lower-level TeX commands than LaTeX ones. It will work, but `\makebox` or `\adjustbox` is more flexible.

Comment: I don't know how to get this solution to work. I use adjustbox but it throwing error. `Not in outer par mode` It refers to my `\begin{table}[]` code

Comment: I found out the problem is `\begin{adjustbox}{center}` should go just before `\begin{tabular}{ll|l}` not `\begin{table}[]` The answer should be adjusted, as it is not clear what `<your table>` means.

Comment: I don't understand the whole first half of this answer about `\Makebox` and `\makebox` or really why it's important to know... But I will say that the `adjustbox` trick works great!

Comment: @Whitecat: The confusion about `table` and `tabular` is widespread under beginners. The `table` is the floating container which also provides the possibility of a caption and the `tabular` is for creating the actual table, which can also be used outside `table` as long you don't need a caption. I changed my answer to make this more clear.

Comment: @BenjaminMakoHill: By the time I wrote the answer `adjustbox` was relative new and some people might not had it. As a standard LaTeX macro like `\makebox` does the same I also wrote about it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work with longtables :-/

Comment: I don't think this answer works. At least not if you are using booktabs for tables.

Comment: @oulenz: No, :-), longtables splits the content into several boxes. Content graping commands like `adjustbox` do not work on such code.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist: The `\begin{adjustbox}{tabular=lll,center}` part indeed causes an `! Misplaced \noalign` error if `\toprule` is used at the beginning. In this case just use the long form on top of my answer.

Answer (score 35):

Put your `tabular` block  into `\centerline{}`. The table will extend evenly into both margins if it's wider than `\textwidth`.

Comment: This works great as long as there is no new lines between centerline and the table.

Answer (score 17):

I’ve seen that [an answer based on the use of `\centerline`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39441/69818) has been considered; I then thought that even the following crude hack, that I sometimes employ as a quick one-shot cure for similar situations, could be worth mentioning:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{mwe} % facilitates the writing of Minimale Working Examples like 
                 % this one, not to be used in actual documents



\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
    \addtolength{\leftskip} {-2cm} % increase (absolute) value if needed
    \addtolength{\rightskip}{-2cm}
    \begin{tabular*}{1.2\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|ccc|}
        \hline
        Does & this & table  \\
        really & need & to  \\
        be & so & wide?  \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular*}
\end{center}

It works with floating objects, too: see, for example, figure~\ref{fig:a} and
table~\ref{tab:b}.

\begin{figure}[tbp]
    \centering
    \addtolength{\leftskip} {-2cm}
    \addtolength{\rightskip}{-2cm}
    \includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth,height=5cm]{image}
    \caption{A example image}
    \label{fig:a}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[bp]
    \centering
    \addtolength{\leftskip} {-2cm}
    \addtolength{\rightskip}{-2cm}
    \begin{tabular*}{1.2\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|ccc|}
        \hline
        And & what & about  \\
        this & one, & eh?  \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular*}
    \caption{An example table}
    \label{tab:b}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: `\addtolength{\leftskip}{-2cm}` and `\addtolength{\rightskip}{-2cm}` seems a cleaner solution to me.

Comment: @mmj: I’m afraid I don’t understand: didn’t I do exactly that?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, I should have written explicitly "your solution `\addtolength...` seems cleaner than the others", although it is much less voted.

Comment: @mmj: Oh, *now* I see what you meant!  Indeed, it has been a little silly of me not to understand it in the first place!  And—well—thanks for your appreciation…

Comment: This answer is much easier to get working. At least if you are working with non-floating tables.