# TikZ plot: centering and units on axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, horizontal-alignment, plot

I have the following.

[image: screenshot in pdf reader]

I'm trying to center the plot and putting `\begin{center}` around the TikZ image does not work.

Also I'm trying to change the units of the x-axis. The x-axis is used to represent the time. The axis is currently using seconds and I had to zoom in with xmin and xmax to get the result. Now there is a `*10^(-2)` at the bottom but I would like to have milliseconds or microseconds labeled at each tick.

This is the code I have now.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=tijd,
    ycomb, ymin=0, ymax=4, xmin=0.0248, xmax=0.0255,
    enlarge y limits=false,
    width=15cm, height=5cm,
    tick align = outside,
    grid = major,
    %scaled x ticks = false,
    yticklabels={X, 0, settings, macroblock, picture},
    %x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed}
    ]
\addplot +[mark=none] table {seperatemb.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: You should make sure that your examples are compilable. In this case, you need to include a preamble (starting from `\documentclass`), and you should include some dummy data.

Comment: About the centering problem: Your plot is most likely too wide for the text area (no way of telling without knowing your documentclass and setup). You can either decrease the width of the plot, or wrap it in `\begin{adjustbox}{center}` (see [How can I center a too wide table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39435/how-can-i-center-a-too-wide-table)), or use `trim axis left` in the `\begin{tikzpicture}[...]` options to make the y tick labels not count towards the bounding box.

Comment: Jake, The trim axis left option is ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could transform your data to milliseconds by using `x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1*1000}`, but a more elegant approach would be to use the `units` library, which is loaded using `\pgfplotslibrary{units}` in the preamble. You can then set `x unit=s` to specify that the data is in seconds, set `change x base=true` to allow pgfplots to transform the data, and then set `x SI prefix=milli` to change the units to milliseconds.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=tijd,
    ycomb, ymin=0, ymax=4, xmin=0.0248, xmax=0.0255,
    enlarge y limits=false,
    width=15cm, height=5cm,
    tick align = outside,
    grid = major,
    %scaled x ticks = false,
    yticklabels={X, 0, settings, macroblock, picture},
    x unit=s,
    change x base=true,
    x SI prefix=milli
    ]
\addplot +[mark=none, ultra thick] table {
0.0249 2
0.0251 1
0.0254 1
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Another quick fix is to add `scaled x ticks=base 10:3,
xtick scale label code/.code={ms}` but `siunitx` is certainly better and has direct support.

Comment: I also like the trick you did with ultra thick, this makes it alot more visible.