# Change unit from a read in data table

Tags: tables, pgfplots, csv

I use pgfplots to create a graph from a csv file. The column that I use for the x-axis contains time values measured in ms. As my timelapse is a bit more as a min I therefor have values between 1000 and 64000. What the graph shows as x-axis marks are numbers from 1 to 7 and a *10^4 mark at the end. 
What I would like to have are 10 second marks. Is there some way to change the unit (or just divide by 1000 and then tell to show the 10, the 20 etc)?

Comment: Take a look at [TikZ plot: centering and units on axis](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60549/tikz-plot-centering-and-units-on-axis/60553#60553).

Comment: @dhyr: did Jake's link solve your question?