# Pgfplots, Units and "Modify Number Data Scale"

Tags: pgfplots, units, siunits

I've got a question with `tikzpicture` in LaTeX.
Data of Tikzpicture are in a external file. The y-axis scale is like: 100,000 - 150,000... (thousands). I need to put the scale of this axis like 100 - 150 - 200..., and put "K_unit" on the axis label.

I've tried so many options, but nothing works. The last approximation that I've followed was to use the library units from pgfplots, as in: [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60549/tikz-plot-centering-and-units-on-axis). It works, but shows "[unit]" in the axis label. Two questions:

1) Is it possible to remove the unit text, or customize axis label with the previous approximation?

2) Is there another option "to reduce the scale of my data"?

Comment: Hi and [welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/32374) Its not quite clear what your question is, so can you please post a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/32374) with some sample data, starting at `\documentclass{...}` and ending at `\end{document}`? Also, you may have noticed that I edited your post - we prefer not to say thanks or sign our names here. No one will think you're rude, and your name appears in the bottom right of all your posts anyways. Just trying to help focus the question on what you need :-)

Comment: Is the `scaled ticks` option on page 286 of the pgfplots 1.10 manual what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

To reduce the x scale you could use the code key 'x filter', such as the example on page 329 in pgfplots_1.10:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[x filter/.code=
{\pgfmathdivide{#1}{1000}}]
\addplot coordinates {
(4,0)
(6,1)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Then you could insert the kilo-unit in your xlabel: `xlabel={Quantity~[k-unit]}` to make it clear for the reader that you did the manipulation. This example is for the x-scale, and the same holds for y-scale.