# Move table to the left of the page

Tags: tables

As I run the TeX, it seems that table is exceeded the page. How I can move it to the left of the page so that the table is positioned nicely at the middle of the page? Here is my code:-

```
  \documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{amsfonts}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{center}
  \includegraphics{ftab.png}

 {\Large \textbf{F Table for $ \alpha = 0.025 $ }}{\normalsize ($\frac{1}{3}$})

 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
 \hline  \textbf{df2/df1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{8} & \textbf{9} \\ 
 \hline  \textbf{1}  & 647.7890& 799.4822   & 864.15    & 899.5833  & 921.8479  & 937.1111  & 948.2169  & 956.6562  & 963.2846 \\
 \hline  \textbf{2}  & 38.5063 & 39.0000    & 39.166    & 39.2484   & 39.2982   & 39.3315   & 39.3553   & 39.3730   & 39.3869  \\
 \hline  \textbf{3}  & 17.4434 & 16.0442    & 15.439    & 15.1010   & 14.8848   & 14.7347   & 14.6244   & 14.5399   & 14.4731  \\
 \hline  \textbf{4}  & 12.2179 & 10.6491    & 9.9792    & 9.6045    & 9.3645    & 9.1973    & 9.0741    & 8.9796    & 8.9047   \\ 
 \hline  \textbf{5}  & 10.0070 & 8.4336 & 7.7636    & 7.3879    & 7.1464    & 6.9777    & 6.8530    & 6.7572    & 6.6811   \\
 \hline \textbf{6}  & 8.8131     & 7.2599   & 6.5988    & 6.2271    & 5.9876    & 5.8197    & 5.6955    & 5.5996    & 5.5234   \\
 \hline  \textbf{7}  & 8.0727    & 6.5415   & 5.8898    & 5.5226    & 5.2852    & 5.1186    & 4.9949    & 4.8993    & 4.8232   \\
 \hline  \textbf{8}  & 7.5709    & 6.0595   & 5.4120    & 5.0526    & 4.8173    & 4.6517    & 4.5285    & 4.4333    & 4.3572   \\
 \hline  \textbf{9}  & 7.2093    & 5.7147   & 5.0781    & 4.7181    & 4.4844    & 4.3197    & 4.1970    & 4.1020    & 4.0260   \\ 
 \hline  \textbf{10} & 6.9367    & 5.4564   & 4.8256    & 4.4684    & 4.2361    & 4.0721    & 3.9498    & 3.8549    & 3.7790   \\ 
 \hline  \textbf{11} & 6.7241    & 5.2559   & 4.6300    & 4.2751    & 4.0440    & 3.8806    & 3.7586    & 3.6638    & 3.5879   \\
 \hline  \textbf{12} & 6.5538    & 5.0959   & 4.4742    & 4.1212    & 3.8911    & 3.7283    & 3.6065    & 3.5118    & 3.4358    \\
 \hline  \textbf{13} & 6.4143    & 4.9653   & 4.3472    & 3.9959    & 3.7667    & 3.6043    & 3.4827    & 3.3880    & 3.3120   \\
 \hline  \textbf{14} & 6.2979    & 4.8567   & 4.2417    & 3.8919    & 3.6634    & 3.5014    & 3.3799    & 3.2854    & 3.2093 \\
 \hline  \textbf{15} & 6.1995    & 4.7650   & 4.1528    & 3.8043    & 3.5764    & 3.4147    & 3.2934    & 3.1987    & 3.1227 \\
 \hline  \textbf{16} & 6.1151    & 4.6867   & 4.0768    & 3.7294    & 3.5021    & 3.3406    & 3.2194    & 3.1248    & 3.0488\\  
 \hline  \textbf{17} & 6.0420    & 4.6189   & 4.0111    & 3.6648    & 3.4380    & 3.2767    & 3.1556    & 3.0610    & 2.9849\\  
\hline  \textbf{18} & 5.9781     & 4.5597   & 3.9539    & 3.6083    & 3.3820    & 3.2209    & 3.0999    & 3.0053    & 2.9291 \\ 
\hline  \textbf{19} & 5.9216     & 4.5075   & 3.9034    & 3.5587    & 3.3327    & 3.1719    & 3.0509    & 2.9564    & 2.8801 \\
\hline  \textbf{20} & 5.8715     & 4.4612   & 3.8587    & 3.5147    & 3.2891    & 3.1284    & 3.0074    & 2.9128    & 2.8365 \\
\hline  \textbf{21} & 5.8266     & 4.4199   & 3.8188    & 3.4754    & 3.2501    & 3.0895    & 2.9686    & 2.8740    & 2.7977 \\ 
\hline  \textbf{22} & 5.7863     & 4.3828   & 3.7829    & 3.4401    & 3.2151    & 3.0546    & 2.9338    & 2.8392    & 2.7628 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Thank you for the concern and help.

Comment: Use a `\makebox`, as in  `\makebox[\linewidth]{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}...\end{tabular}}`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I center a too wide table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39435/5764)

Answer (score 1):

For the table at hand, I would strongly recommend *not* compressing it to make it fit into the width of the text block -- unless you're prepared to distribute free magnifying glasses with the document. :-) Instead, consider typesetting the table uncompressed in landscape mode, as is done in the example below with the help of the [rotating](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/rotating/) package and its `sidewaystable` environment.

Two additional recommendations: First, get rid of all vertical lines and most horizontal lines and retainjust three horizontal lines -- to be drawn with `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` (from the [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/) package. Trust me, all those vertical and horizontal lines mostly provide clutter, not visual information. Second, align the numerical data on the decimal points to make it easier for readers to take in the information that's being presented. Aligning the numbers in this fashion can be done with the help of the [dcolumn](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/dcolumn/) package, or with the `S` column type provided by the [siunitx](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn,booktabs,rotating}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
%%\caption{A landscape-mode table} %% optional
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{9}{d{3.4}} @{}} 
\toprule
\textbf{df2/df1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{8} & \textbf{9} \\ 
\midrule
\textbf{1}  & 647.7890& 799.4822   & 864.15    & 899.5833  & 921.8479  & 937.1111  & 948.2169  & 956.6562  & 963.2846 \\
   \textbf{2}  & 38.5063 & 39.0000    & 39.166    & 39.2484   & 39.2982   & 39.3315   & 39.3553   & 39.3730   & 39.3869  \\
   \textbf{3}  & 17.4434 & 16.0442    & 15.439    & 15.1010   & 14.8848   & 14.7347   & 14.6244   & 14.5399   & 14.4731  \\
   \textbf{4}  & 12.2179 & 10.6491    & 9.9792    & 9.6045    & 9.3645    & 9.1973    & 9.0741    & 8.9796    & 8.9047   \\ 
   \textbf{5}  & 10.0070 & 8.4336 & 7.7636    & 7.3879    & 7.1464    & 6.9777    & 6.8530    & 6.7572    & 6.6811   \\
  \textbf{6}  & 8.8131     & 7.2599   & 6.5988    & 6.2271    & 5.9876    & 5.8197    & 5.6955    & 5.5996    & 5.5234   \\
   \textbf{7}  & 8.0727    & 6.5415   & 5.8898    & 5.5226    & 5.2852    & 5.1186    & 4.9949    & 4.8993    & 4.8232   \\
   \textbf{8}  & 7.5709    & 6.0595   & 5.4120    & 5.0526    & 4.8173    & 4.6517    & 4.5285    & 4.4333    & 4.3572   \\
   \textbf{9}  & 7.2093    & 5.7147   & 5.0781    & 4.7181    & 4.4844    & 4.3197    & 4.1970    & 4.1020    & 4.0260   \\ 
   \textbf{10} & 6.9367    & 5.4564   & 4.8256    & 4.4684    & 4.2361    & 4.0721    & 3.9498    & 3.8549    & 3.7790   \\ 
   \textbf{11} & 6.7241    & 5.2559   & 4.6300    & 4.2751    & 4.0440    & 3.8806    & 3.7586    & 3.6638    & 3.5879   \\
   \textbf{12} & 6.5538    & 5.0959   & 4.4742    & 4.1212    & 3.8911    & 3.7283    & 3.6065    & 3.5118    & 3.4358    \\
   \textbf{13} & 6.4143    & 4.9653   & 4.3472    & 3.9959    & 3.7667    & 3.6043    & 3.4827    & 3.3880    & 3.3120   \\
   \textbf{14} & 6.2979    & 4.8567   & 4.2417    & 3.8919    & 3.6634    & 3.5014    & 3.3799    & 3.2854    & 3.2093 \\
   \textbf{15} & 6.1995    & 4.7650   & 4.1528    & 3.8043    & 3.5764    & 3.4147    & 3.2934    & 3.1987    & 3.1227 \\
   \textbf{16} & 6.1151    & 4.6867   & 4.0768    & 3.7294    & 3.5021    & 3.3406    & 3.2194    & 3.1248    & 3.0488\\  
   \textbf{17} & 6.0420    & 4.6189   & 4.0111    & 3.6648    & 3.4380    & 3.2767    & 3.1556    & 3.0610    & 2.9849\\  
  \textbf{18} & 5.9781     & 4.5597   & 3.9539    & 3.6083    & 3.3820    & 3.2209    & 3.0999    & 3.0053    & 2.9291 \\ 
  \textbf{19} & 5.9216     & 4.5075   & 3.9034    & 3.5587    & 3.3327    & 3.1719    & 3.0509    & 2.9564    & 2.8801 \\
  \textbf{20} & 5.8715     & 4.4612   & 3.8587    & 3.5147    & 3.2891    & 3.1284    & 3.0074    & 2.9128    & 2.8365 \\
  \textbf{21} & 5.8266     & 4.4199   & 3.8188    & 3.4754    & 3.2501    & 3.0895    & 2.9686    & 2.8740    & 2.7977 \\ 
  \textbf{22} & 5.7863     & 4.3828   & 3.7829    & 3.4401    & 3.2151    & 3.0546    & 2.9338    & 2.8392    & 2.7628 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```