# Centering an image vertically

Tags: graphics, positioning

I'm currently having a few problems with centering an image on a page (both vertically and horizontally) while enlarging the image so that it is taking the whole width of the page.

I'm managing to center the picture horizontally, but not vertically. The code below shows the version I made that centers the image horizontally. My question is here what can I do to center it also vertically?

I'm having an srcbook class .tex:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,BCOR10mm,DIV11,toc=listof,parskip=full]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}            
\usepackage{multicol}
```

I'm currently positioning the image like this:

```
\centerline\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{MyImage.jpg}
```

Comment: before the `\centerline` (which isn't the most "latexy" way to do this), add `\vspace*{\fill}` and add `\vspace{\fill}` after it.  the starred version will keep the space from disappearing at the top of a page.  as for the `\centerline`, that's a holdover from plain tex.  a "better" way (or at least one with better latex syntax) is to use `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` to "wrap" it.

Comment: Related: [Center figure that is wider than `\textwidth`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582/5764); [How can I center a too wide table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39435/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\centerline` takes an argument so in

```
\centerline\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{MyImage.jpg}
```

the argument is just `\noindent`

so it is equivalent to

```
\centerline{\noindent}%
\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{MyImage.jpg}}
```

so you get one blank white line from the `\centerline` then an overfull box with the image.

possibly you want

```
\vspace*{\fill}
\noindent
\hspace*{-\oddsidemargin}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{MyImage.jpg}}
\vspace*{\fill}
```

I am assuming here you did intend your image to be as wide as the paper not just as wide as the text block, so covering both margins.

Comment: the last part results in an compile error for me (runaway argument file ended while scanning \@imakebox (seemingly at \includegraphics))

Comment: @ThomasE. was missing a `}` If you had supplied a test file in your question I'd have tested it:-)

Comment: tnx functions that way. albeit a bit smaller in width than pagewidth

Comment: tnx = thank you (sry did take up on that shortcut for thank you thanks to MMORPGs). Found an issue with how the graphics is displyed, but that has nothing to do with the original question and the answer to it. will probably make a second question there if I can't solve the problem. So thank you again for the answer helped a lot there!

Comment: What if you want to add a caption?

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
\centering\includegraphics{xyz}
\vfill\null
\end{document}
```

### How to prove?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{foo.tex}
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
\centering\includegraphics{xyz}
\vfill\null
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\immediate\write18{pdflatex foo}
\immediate\write18{pdftops -f 1 -l 1 -eps foo.pdf}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics{foo}}

\psset
{
    xunit=0.1\wd\IBox,
    yunit=0.1\ht\IBox,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](10,10)
    \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\centering` will not do anything if the image is wider than `\textwidth` as in the OP's case.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I see. In this answer I mainly just concentrated on the vertical alignment.

Comment: Thanks PSTricks for helping me to prove it geometrically.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{MyImage.jpg}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
```

Comment: that will be over full (and not centred) in the usual case that `\paperwidth` is greater than `\textwidth`

Answer (score 2):

The image can easily be centered horizontally and vertically via package `pdfpages`. It also enlarges the image as much as possible to fit into the paper area without distorting the image.

Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,BCOR=10mm,DIV=11]{scrbook}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
  \includepdf{MyImage.jpg}
\end{document}
```

Option `BCOR` is not taken into account, when placing the image. Some white space can be added to the left or right of the image via option `trim`:

```
\includepdf[trim=-5mm 0 -8mm 0]{MyImage.jpg}
```

Would add a white margin of 5mm to the left and 8mm to the right of the *unscaled* image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use TikZ:

```
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node [inner sep = 0] at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{image.jpg}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
```