# How to vertically align and scale images within a tabularx environment

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, tabularx

How does one scale the images and also vertically centre align the images.

**Relevant Research:**

I have looked at the following links to better understand and try out their recommendations:

- [LaTeX \includegraphics and textline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147707/latex-includegraphics-and-textline)
- [Centering an image vertically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192718/centering-an-image-vertically)
- [Vertical alignment of subfigures LATEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328403/vertical-alignment-of-subfigures-latex)

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\makeatother
\newcommand*\bigrightArrow[1][0pt]{\color{black!40}\raisebox{#1}{\scalebox{2.4}[3.6]{\ding{225}}}}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}

Some text \textbf{above} the image.
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XcXcX@{}}
    \subcaptionbox{text 1}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
    &
    \bigrightArrow[20pt]
    &
    \subcaptionbox{text 2}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
    &
    \bigrightArrow[20pt]
    &
    \subcaptionbox{text 3}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
    \\
  \end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
Some text \textbf{underneath} the image.
\end{document}
```

**Current Output:**

[image]

**Ideal Output:**

[image]

**Question:**

How does one:

- vertically align an image within the above MWE
- scale an image within the above MWE

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `tabularx` with 3 `X` type columns? They will then be of equal width but your desired screen shot seems to indicate the last one should be smaller.

Comment: Finally found a solution {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]} becomes {\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth] which further scales down.... couldn't do the vertical alignment - but it's good enough for the time being.

Comment: There are dedicated packages like `floatrow` or `makecell` for that.

Answer (score 2):

See if the following solution is acceptable to you:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newcommand\bigrightArrow{
\tikz[baseline=-3pt]
{
\draw[line width=12pt,-{Triangle[length=16pt, width=24pt]}, gray] 
    (0,0) -- ++ (32pt,0);
}
                        }

\begin{document}
Some text \textbf{above} the image.
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
% with width of `X` column is defined image size
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X c 
                                   >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X c 
                                   >{\hsize=0.6\hsize}X   
                               @{}}
\includegraphics[width=\hsize, valign=c]{example-image-a}
    & \bigrightArrow 
        & \includegraphics[width=\hsize, valign=c]{example-image-b} 
            & \bigrightArrow 
                & \includegraphics[width=\hsize, valign=c]{example-image-c}          \\
\subcaptionbox{text 1}{\rule{\hsize}{0pt}}
    &&  \subcaptionbox{text 2}{\rule{\hsize}{0pt}}
        &&  \subcaptionbox{text 3}{\rule{\hsize}{0pt}}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
Some text \textbf{underneath} the image.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) here.

The following uses `\hfill`s to spread the content across the page in the same way `tabularx` does. In order to vertically align different sized images, you can capture the differing elements inside boxes (`\bigbox` and `\smallbox` below) from which you can extract their respective `h`eigh`t`s. This allows you to raise them into position so they are vertically centred.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,pifont,xcolor}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand*\bigrightArrow[1][0pt]
  {\color{black!40}\raisebox{#1}{\scalebox{2.4}[3.6]{\ding{225}}}}

\newsavebox{\smallbox}% A box to store a small(er) image
\newsavebox{\bigbox}% A box to store a large(r) image

\begin{document}

Some text \textbf{above} the image.
\begin{figure}[!h]

  \mbox{}\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{text 1}{\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill
  \bigrightArrow[13pt]\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{text 2}{\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image-b}}\hfill
  \bigrightArrow[13pt]\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{text 3}{\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image-c}}\hfill
  \mbox{}%

  \bigskip

  \savebox{\bigbox}{\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}}% Large(r) image
  \savebox{\smallbox}{\includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image-c}}% Small(er) image
  \mbox{}\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{text 1}{\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill
  \bigrightArrow[13pt]\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{text 2}{\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image-b}}\hfill
  \bigrightArrow[13pt]\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{text 3}{~~\raisebox{\dimexpr.5\ht\bigbox-.5\ht\smallbox}{\usebox{\smallbox}}~~}\hfill
  \mbox{}%

\end{figure}

Some text \textbf{underneath} the image.

\end{document}
```