# problem centering table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have tried many combinations for centering following table, but none seems to work... Help much appreciated..

```
 \RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}

  \usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts, amssymb, mathtools}
  \usepackage[algoruled,lined,linesnumbered,titlenotnumbered]{algorithm2e}
  \usepackage{array}
  \usepackage{booktabs}
  \usepackage{color}
  \usepackage{comment}
  \usepackage{fixltx2e}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
  \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage{listings}
  \usepackage{microtype}
  \usepackage{multirow}
  \usepackage{pdfpages}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepackage{siunitx}
  \usepackage{float}

  \usepackage{subfigure}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{center}
  \begin{table}[!ht] 

  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|p{8.5cm}|} 
  \hline
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
   legend style={fill=none},
   xlabel={Time}, 
   ylabel={Values}
   ]

   \pgfkeys{
   /pgf/number format/precision=5, 
}

\pgfplotstableread
{
thread  speedup
24   321.179125106 
48   324.194761473  
309  341.576483167 
}\datafile

\addplot table[x=thread,y=speedup,color=red,mark=x] {\datafile};
\addlegendentry{a=10, b=10}

\pgfplotstableread
{
thread  speedup
24   321.166812198 
48   324.1978397  
309  341.561092032 
}\datafile

\addplot table[x=thread,y=speedup,color=red,mark=x] {\datafile};
\addlegendentry{a=10, b=5}

\pgfplotstableread
{
thread  speedup
24   324.968422522 
48   327.766530848   
309  343.636843094 
}\datafile

\addplot table[x=thread,y=speedup,color=red,mark=x] {\datafile};
\addlegendentry{a=10, b=1}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  & 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  legend style={fill=none},
  xlabel={Time}, 
  ylabel={Values }
 ]

\pgfkeys{
  /pgf/number format/precision=5, 
}

\pgfplotstableread
{
thread  speedup
24  321.179125106  
48  324.194761473   
309 341.576483167 
}\datafile

\addplot table[x=thread,y=speedup,color=red,mark=x] {\datafile};
\addlegendentry{a=10, b=10}

\pgfplotstableread
{
thread  speedup
24   321.163733971  
48   324.186552868 
309  341.564170259 
}\datafile

\addplot table[x=thread,y=speedup,color=red,mark=x] {\datafile};
\addlegendentry{a=10, b=5}

\pgfplotstableread
{
thread  speedup
24  322.213409372 
48  325.215706756 
309 342.349118139 
}\datafile

\addplot table[x=thread,y=speedup,color=red,mark=x] {\datafile};
\addlegendentry{a=10, b=1}


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   \\

Parameter1 & Parameter2\\
\hline
\end{tabular}



\caption{Caption}
\label{table:time}
\end{table}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [How can I center a too wide table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39435)

Comment: also do not put `center` around the outside of `table` (it just adds spurious space without centering anything) use `\centering` _inside_ `\begin{table}`

Comment: The `subfigure` package is deprecated; use either `subfig` or `subcaption`.

Comment: off topics: `mathtools` kind of loads `amsmath` so just load the prior. Load `xcolor` instead of `color`, use `subcaption` instead of `subfigure`, `pgfplots` loads `tikz` so that's redundant. Do not use `\begin{center}` unless you know, what you are doing. If you load `booktabs` you should also use that nice package... (maybe not here). Last thing: You might want to use the legend style `legend style={at={(0.02,0.98)},anchor=north west},legend cell align=left,`

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Centering needs to be applied within the float, not around it. There was a spurious third column in the `tabular` and I scaled the two `tikzpicture` a bit so they fitted.

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}

  \usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts, amssymb, mathtools}
  \usepackage[algoruled,lined,linesnumbered,titlenotnumbered]{algorithm2e}
  \usepackage{array}
  \usepackage{booktabs}
  \usepackage{color}
  \usepackage{comment}
  \usepackage{fixltx2e}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
  \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage{listings}
  \usepackage{microtype}
  \usepackage{multirow}
  \usepackage{pdfpages}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepackage{siunitx}
  \usepackage{float}

  \usepackage{subfigure}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{table}[!ht] \centering

  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|} 
  \hline
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
  \begin{axis}[
   legend style={fill=none},
   xlabel={Time}, 
   ylabel={Values}
   ]

   \pgfkeys{
   /pgf/number format/precision=5, 
}

\pgfplotstableread
{
thread  speedup
24   321.179125106 
48   324.194761473  
309  341.576483167 
}\datafile

\addplot table[x=thread,y=speedup,color=red,mark=x] {\datafile};
\addlegendentry{a=10, b=10}

\pgfplotstableread
{
thread  speedup
24   321.166812198 
48   324.1978397  
309  341.561092032 
}\datafile

\addplot table[x=thread,y=speedup,color=red,mark=x] {\datafile};
\addlegendentry{a=10, b=5}

\pgfplotstableread
{
thread  speedup
24   324.968422522 
48   327.766530848   
309  343.636843094 
}\datafile

\addplot table[x=thread,y=speedup,color=red,mark=x] {\datafile};
\addlegendentry{a=10, b=1}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  & 

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{axis}[
  legend style={fill=none},
  xlabel={Time}, 
  ylabel={Values }
 ]

\pgfkeys{
  /pgf/number format/precision=5, 
}

\pgfplotstableread
{
thread  speedup
24  321.179125106  
48  324.194761473   
309 341.576483167 
}\datafile

\addplot table[x=thread,y=speedup,color=red,mark=x] {\datafile};
\addlegendentry{a=10, b=10}

\pgfplotstableread
{
thread  speedup
24   321.163733971  
48   324.186552868 
309  341.564170259 
}\datafile

\addplot table[x=thread,y=speedup,color=red,mark=x] {\datafile};
\addlegendentry{a=10, b=5}

\pgfplotstableread
{
thread  speedup
24  322.213409372 
48  325.215706756 
309 342.349118139 
}\datafile

\addplot table[x=thread,y=speedup,color=red,mark=x] {\datafile};
\addlegendentry{a=10, b=1}


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   \\

Parameter1 & Parameter2\\
\hline
\end{tabular}



\caption{Caption}
\label{table:time}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```