# Aligning headers with column better

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

The columns are slightly offset from the headers. I've tried playing around with a bunch of things (which is why the code is a bit of a mess now). Any suggestions how to fix this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol, booktabs, pbox}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\begin{document}
{
\def\sep{0.5em}
\def\fns{\footnotesize}
\def\onepc{$^{\ast\ast}$} \def\fivepc{$^{\ast}$}
\def\tenpc{$^{\dag}$}
\def\legend{\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize{Significance levels
:\hspace{1em} $\dag$ : 10\% \hspace{1em}
$\ast$ : 5\% \hspace{1em} $\ast\ast$ : 1\% \normalsize}}}
\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering
  \ra{1.2}
  \hspace*{-1.5cm}\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{1cm}} r @{} l@{\hspace{1cm}} r @{} l@{\hspace{1cm}} r @{} l@{\hspace{1cm}} r @{} l }
    \toprule
    &  \pbox{3cm}{Daily Spending \\ \small (all goods)}& &  \pbox{3cm}{ Daily Spending \\ \small (full tax goods)}& &  \pbox{3.5cm}{ Daily Spending \\ \small (discount tax goods)}&\\[\sep]
    \midrule
    Varvarvarvar  & -0.0168&\onepc & -0.0046& & -0.0191&\onepc \\
    \bottomrule
    \legend
  \end{tabular}\hspace*{-1cm}
\caption{Results for regressions similar to those in Table \ref{regs:Daily}, but at the monthly level rather than daily.   \label{regs:Monthly}}
\end{table}
}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: code is now working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `makecell`, `threeparttable` and `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol, booktabs, pbox}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\usepackage{makecell, threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format = -1.4, table-space-text-post = **}

\begin{document}
%
%\def\sep{0.5em}
%\def\fns{\footnotesize}
\def\onepc{$^{\ast\ast}$} \def\fivepc{$^{\ast}$}
\def\tenpc{$^{\dag}$}
%\def\legend{\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize{Significance levels
%:\hspace{1em} $\dag$ : 10\% \hspace{1em}
%$\ast$ : 5\% \hspace{1em} $\ast\ast$ : 1\% \normalsize}}}
%\begin{table}[!ht]
% \centering
% \ra{1.2}
% \hspace*{-1.5cm}\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{1cm}} r @{} l@{\hspace{1cm}} r @{} l@{\hspace{1cm}} r @{} l@{\hspace{1cm}} r @{} l }
% \toprule
% & \pbox{3cm}{Daily Spending \\ \small (all goods)}& & \pbox{3cm}{ Daily Spending \\ \small (full tax goods)}& & \pbox{3.5cm}{ Daily Spending \\ \small (discount tax goods)}&\\[\sep]
% \midrule
% Varvarvarvar & -0.0168&\onepc & -0.0046& & -0.0191&\onepc \\
% \bottomrule
% \legend
% \end{tabular}\hspace*{-1cm}
%\caption{Results for regressions similar to those in Table \ref{regs:Daily}, but at the monthly level rather than daily. \label{regs:Monthly}}
%\end{table}


\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering\setlength\tabcolsep{1.2em}
  \ra{1.2}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{@{\,}l SSS@{\,}}
      \toprule
                   & {\makecell{Daily Spending & & \\ \small (all goods)}}& {\makecell{ Daily Spending \\ \small (full tax goods)}} & {\makecell{ Daily Spending \\ \small (discount tax goods)}} \\[0.5em]
      \midrule
      Varvarvarvar & -0.0168\onepc & -0.0046 & -0.0191\onepc \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \smallskip
    \begin{tablenotes}[online, para]\footnotesize
      \item[]Significance levels
      \item[$\dag$] : 10\,\%
      \item[$\ast$] : 5\,\% \
      \item[$\ast\ast$] : 1\,\%
    \end{tablenotes}
    \caption{Results for regressions similar to those in Table \ref{regs:Daily}, but at the monthly level rather than daily. \label{regs:Monthly}}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Rather than fixing the problem with `\pbox` and similar hacks, here's how I would typeset this table.

First of all, a numeric table should *always* use `siunitx` facilities. Second, repeating data is evil.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol, booktabs, siunitx}

\newcommand\onepc{$^{\ast\ast}$}
\newcommand\fivepc{$^{\ast}$}
\newcommand\tenpc{$^{\dag}$}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering

\begin{tabular}{ l *{3}{S[table-format=-1.4,table-space-text-post=\onepc]} }
\toprule
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Daily Spending on goods} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
  &  {all} & {full tax} & {discount tax} \\
\midrule
Varvarvarvar  & -0.0168\onepc & -0.0046 & -0.0191\onepc \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize
  Significance levels:\quad $\dag$: 10\% \quad $\ast$: 5\% \quad $\ast\ast$: 1\%%
}
\end{tabular}

\caption{Results for regressions similar to those in Table \ref{regs:Daily}, but at the 
monthly level rather than daily.}\label{regs:Monthly}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note that the table specification says that the three numeric columns share the format: a possible sign `-`, one digit in the integral part, four in the decimal part and some added space as wide as `\onepc`.

There is no need to increase `\arraystretch`, nor to reduce the font size in the headers. The common part is stated as a global header, the specific part typeset as subheaders.

Never leave space in front of colons.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're setting the heading in a `\parbox` of pre-specified width. Since you're using a manual line-breaking inside these `\parbox`es, you might just as well set them in a `tabular` which will expand to the natural width of the content. [`makecell`](http://ctan.org/pkg/makecell) simplifies this input:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell}
\newcommand\ra{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}}
\newcommand\sep{0.5em}
\newcommand\fns{\footnotesize}
\newcommand\onepc{$^{\ast\ast}$} \def\fivepc{$^{\ast}$}
\newcommand\tenpc{$^{\dag}$}
\newcommand\legend{\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize{Significance levels
:\hspace{1em} $\dag$ : 10\% \hspace{1em}
$\ast$ : 5\% \hspace{1em} $\ast\ast$ : 1\% \normalsize}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering
  \ra{1.2}%
  \makebox[\textwidth]{% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39435/5764
    \begin{tabular}{ *{4}{l @{\hspace{1cm}} r @{}} l }
      \toprule
      & \makecell[l]{Daily Spending \\ \small (all goods)} & 
        & \makecell[l]{Daily Spending \\ \small (full tax goods)} & 
        & \makecell[l]{Daily Spending \\ \small (discount tax goods)} & \\[\sep]
      \midrule
      Varvarvarvar  & -0.0168&\onepc & -0.0046& & -0.0191&\onepc \\
      \bottomrule
      \legend
    \end{tabular}}
  \caption{Results for regressions similar to those in Table XX, but at the monthly level rather than daily.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```