# Change geometry of single table

Tags: tables, margins, geometry

I have a wide table, which by default makes the page look like:

```
|    xxxxxx         |
|    xxxxxx         |
|    ______________ |
|    |             ||
|    |             ||
|    ______________ |
|    xxxxxx         |
|    xxxxx          |
```

I'd  like it look like:

```
|    xxxxxx         |
|    xxxxxx         |
|  ________________ |
| |                ||
| |                ||
|  ________________ |
|    xxxxxx         |
|    xxxxx          |
```

I have tried setting the geomotry:

```
\newgeometry{left=0.2in, right=0.2in}
\begin{table}
.....
\end{table}
\restoregeometry
```

But this will create a single page for the table.

Comment: Often, (if L/R symmetry is desired) using `\makebox[\textwidth]{...overwide object...}` will suffice.  If you are not in a centering environment, you may also need a leading `\noindent`.

Comment: Do you mean you want the overwide table to extend into both margins, rather than only the right margin?

Comment: Please see [How can I center a too wide table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39435)

Comment: Also (this one's even more comprehensive; sorry, I didn't find it right way): [Center figure that is wider than \textwidth](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582)