# Make tikz image span paper width

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like a tikz picture to move over to the left so it is touching the edge of the page.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}
    \resizebox{\paperwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \fill[black!50!blue] (-10, 1) rectangle (10, 2);
            \fill[black!50!blue] (-5, 0) rectangle (5, 3);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{figure}
```

This is what it looks like at the moment. How would I move it over?

[image]

Comment: [How can I center a too wide table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39436) should be of help I guess.

Comment: Yes it does, but you can't have the `figure` inside the `adjustbox` of course.