# Left Justification of Table Caption in Adjustbox Package

Tags: tables, adjustbox

I want to change the position of table caption to left, i'd appreciate if someone could help, 
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\captionsetup[table]{
    labelsep = newline,
    textfont = sc, 
    name = TABLE, 
    justification=justified,
    singlelinecheck=false,%%%%%%% a single line is centered by default
    labelsep=colon,%%%%%%
    skip = \medskipamount}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Variables and Definitions}\label{table:2}
    \begin{adjustbox}{center}
        \begin{tabular}{ l p{10.5cm} p{3cm}}
            \hline\hline   
            Variables &  Definition & Source \\  \hline\hline   
            POV    & Measured as Poverty Headcount ratio at \$ 2 a day           & WDI                    \\   
            PG     & Measured as Poverty gap at \$ 2 a day       & WDI                   \\  
            GINI   & Income Inequality, natural log of GINI coefficient  &  WDI     \\   \hline                              
            \hline\hline    
            \multicolumn{3}{l}{%
                \begin{minipage}{16cm}%
                    \tiny Note: $+$The World Bank, World Development Indicators (WDI). %
                \end{minipage}%
            }\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

\end{document}

Comment: BTW, you have two \captionsetup s (the first will be ignored).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `adjustbox`for this table, if you simply  use the `l` specifier for the last column. It all can be done with the `threeparttable` and `tablenotes` environments. I also took the liberty to replace your `\hline`s with rules from the `booktabs` package, and add some vertical padding to the rows with `\addlinespace` from the same package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\captionsetup[table]{
labelsep = newline,
textfont = sc,
name = TABLE,
justification=justified,
singlelinecheck=false,%%%%%%% a single line is centered by default
labelsep=colon,%%%%%%
skip = \medskipamount}
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}[online]
    \caption{Variables and Definitions}\label{table:2}
    \begin{tabular}{lp{10.5cm}l}
      \toprule\midrule
      Variables & Definition & Source \\
      \midrule\midrule
      POV & Measured as Poverty Headcount ratio at \$ 2 a day & WDI \\
      \addlinespace
      PG & Measured as Poverty gap at \$ 2 a day & WDI \\
      \addlinespace
      GINI & Income Inequality, natural log of GINI coefficient & WDI \\
      \midrule \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}[online]\medskip
      \tiny \item[Note:] $+$The World Bank, World Development Indicators (WDI). %
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @BernardThank you so much for your answer, actully i used adjustbox because this table doesn't fit on the page, i used the above code, the table is not in the centre.

Comment: Is it far from fitting the table width? You can play with various parameters (`\tabcolsep`, `fontsize` inside the table, &c.). As a  last resort, you can use `tabularx` and set the table to `textwidth`. Could you post a representative example of your problems?

Answer (score 1):

The following uses [How can I center a too wide table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39435/5764) for centering the table, and [`changepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage)'s `adjustwidth` to make the appropriate room for the `\caption` to match the `tabular` layout. While The original layout suggested that the caption be moved over the width of the first column (which contains `Variables` as its widest entry). However, eyeballing it would have also sufficed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{caption,lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs,changepage}

\captionsetup[table]{
    labelsep = newline,
    textfont = sc, 
    name = TABLE, 
    justification=justified,
    singlelinecheck=false,%%%%%%% a single line is centered by default
    labelsep=colon,%%%%%%
    skip = \medskipamount}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}
  \makeatletter
  \settowidth{\@tempdima}{Variables}%
  \addtolength{\@tempdima}{2\tabcolsep}%
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-\@tempdima}{\@tempdima}
    \caption{Variables and Definitions}
  \end{adjustwidth}
  \makeatother
  \makebox[\textwidth]{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39436/5764
    \begin{tabular}{ l p{10.5cm} p{3cm}}
      \toprule
      Variables & Definition & Source \\
      \midrule
      POV       & Measured as Poverty Headcount ratio at \$ 2 a day  & WDI \\
      PG        & Measured as Poverty gap at \$ 2 a day              & WDI \\
      GINI      & Income Inequality, natural log of GINI coefficient & WDI \\
      \bottomrule
      \multicolumn{3}{l}{%
        \tiny Note: $+$The World Bank, World Development Indicators (WDI).%
      }
    \end{tabular}%
  }
\end{table}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) was added for pizzaz...