# Scale and center standalone tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, scaling, standalone

I'm having a strange behavior whithin my tex document. I have a large project of several tex files. For my tikz pictures I use the standalone document class and include them via

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
     \includestandalone[mode=buildnew, width=1.0\textwidth]{tikzPicture}
      \caption{caption}
    \label{fig:tikzPicture}
\end{figure}
```

The issue is, that the pictures get smaller than `\textwidth` and if I try to scale them with `scale=1.5` instead of `width=1.0\textwidth` they get left shifted and are not centered any more.

One of my tikz pictures looks like following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{rotating}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{10pt}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\xdefinecolor{midnightBlue}{RGB}{25,25,112}
\xdefinecolor{navy}{RGB}{0,0,128}
\xdefinecolor{fireblick}{RGB}{178,34,34}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=1, 
node distance=0mm,
desc/.style={
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    draw=black, 
    very thick,
     text centered,
    text width=7cm,
    minimum height=12mm,
    fill=midnightBlue!30,
    drop shadow
     },
hByte/.style={
    rectangle,
     rounded corners=1pt,
    draw=black, 
     thick,
    text centered,
     text width=0.6cm,
    minimum height=28mm,
     fill=midnightBlue!30,
    xshift=0.45cm,
    drop shadow
     },
Byte/.style={
    rectangle,
    rounded corners=1pt,
    draw=black, 
    thick,
    text centered,
    text width=0.6cm,
    minimum height=56mm,
    fill=midnightBlue!30,
    xshift=0.45cm,
    drop shadow
    },
qByte/.style={
    rectangle,
     rounded corners=1pt,
    draw=black, 
    thick,
    text centered,
    text width=2.6cm,
    minimum height=10mm,
    fill=midnightBlue!30,
    xshift=1.45cm,
    drop shadow
    },
it/.style={
    fill=blue!10
},
level1/.style={
    minimum height=5mm,
    text width=10cm,
    text centered
},
every node/.style={font=\sffamily}
]
\node at (0cm,0cm) [] (base) {};
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
%draw level 1
\node at ($(base)+(-7cm,3cm)$) [desc, it, text width =4.7cm, xshift=2.5cm] (header) {...};
\node at ($(header.east)-(0cm,0cm)$) [desc, it, text width =6.7cm, xshift=3.5cm] (body) {timeSource};
\node at ($(body.east)-(0cm,0cm)$) [desc, it, text width =2.7cm, xshift=1.5cm] (tlv) {path trace TLV};
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
%draw segments
\def\arrowOffsetOne{0cm,2cm};
\def\arrowOffsetTwo{0cm,1cm};
\draw [darkgray,thin,<->] ($(header.north west)+(\arrowOffsetOne)$) -- ($(tlv.north east)+(\arrowOffsetOne)$) node [black,level1, midway, above=0.1cm] (frame) {Announce Nachricht};
\draw [darkgray,thin,<->] ($(header.north west)+(\arrowOffsetTwo)$) -- ($(header.north east)+(\arrowOffsetTwo)$) node [black,level1, midway, above=0.1cm] (headerLength) {29 Byte};
\draw [darkgray,thin,<->] ($(body.north west)+(\arrowOffsetTwo)$) -- ($(body.north east)+(\arrowOffsetTwo)$) node [black,level1, midway, above=0.1cm] (bodyLength) {1 Byte};
\draw [darkgray,thin,<->] ($(tlv.north west)+(\arrowOffsetTwo)$) -- ($(tlv.north east)+(\arrowOffsetTwo)$) node [black,level1, midway, above=0.1cm] (tlvLenght) {\textgreater 
    4 + 8N Byte};
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
%draw Header
\node at ($(base)+(-5cm,-3cm)$) [qByte, it, fill=orange!20] (node1) {tlvType};
\node at ($(node1.east)-(0.025cm,0cm)$) [qByte, it, fill=red!20] (node2) {lengthField};
\node at ($(node2.east)-(0.025cm,0cm)$) [qByte, it, fill=green!20] (lastnode) {pathSequence};
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
%draw separating lines
\draw [gray,dashed,thin] ($(header.north west)+(\arrowOffsetOne)+(0cm,1cm)$) -- (header.south west);
\draw [gray,dashed,thin] (tlv.south west) -- (node1.north west);

\draw [gray,dashed,thin] ($(body.north west)+(\arrowOffsetTwo)$) -- (body.south west);
\draw [gray,dashed,thin] ($(body.north east)+(\arrowOffsetTwo)$) -- (body.south east);
\draw [gray,dashed,thin] ($(tlv.north east)+(\arrowOffsetOne)+(0cm,1cm)$) -- (tlv.south east);
\draw [gray,dashed,thin] (tlv.south east) -- (lastnode.north east);

\draw [gray,dashed,thin] (node1.south west) -- ($(node1.south west)-(0,0.3)$);
\draw [gray,dashed,thin] (node1.south east) -- ($(node1.south east)-(0,0.3)$);
\draw [gray,dashed,thin] (node2.south east) -- ($(node2.south east)-(0,0.3)$);
\draw [gray,dashed,thin] (lastnode.south east) -- ($(lastnode.south east)-(0,0.3)$);

\node at ($(node1.south west)-(0.5,0.7)$) [black, level1] {Byte};

\draw [darkgray,thin,<->] ($(node1.south west)-(0,0.3)$) -- ($(node1.south east)-(0,0.3)$) node [black,level1, midway, below=0.1cm] {2};
\draw [darkgray,thin,<->] ($(node2.south west)-(0,0.2)$) -- ($(node2.south east)-(0,0.2)$) node [black,level1, midway, below=0.175cm] {2};
\draw [darkgray,thin,<->] ($(lastnode.south west)-(0,0.3)$) -- ($(lastnode.south east)-(0,0.3)$) node [black,level1, midway, below=0.1cm] {8N};
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Does anybody know what could cause this behavior?
Regards,
Efim

Solution: As esdd already told in his comment, the solution is very simple. The reason for that scaling issue was that the setting `text width=10cm` whithin `level1` was enlarging the whole picture. Removing this setting solves the issue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try using `mode=image` instead of `buildnew`. I think `buildnew` uses the picture code and `image` uses the produced Image. The difference is that tikzpictures do not have a `width` option but Images have... (I'm not sure, this is more of a hunch)

Comment: Have you noticed that there is a lot of whitespace on the sides of the diagram? If you fix that, perhaps you get an appropriate scale with `width=\textwidth`. If you make it wider than `\textwidth` (as happens with `scale=1.5`, as far as I can see), the image will stick out into the right margin, or even out of the page. If you want it centered on the textblock you can use `\makebox` or `adjustbox` as discussed in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39435, but modifying the diagram might be just as good a solution.

Comment: There are many excellent users of LaTeX, here. I can suggest `TikzEdt` to verificate your Tikz code. Look the link: http://www.tikzedt.org/.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @GuilhermeZanotelli: changing the mode to mode=image doesn't change the resulting picture.

Comment: @Torbjorn T: I noticed that whitespace on the sides, but I don't know where it comes from. As far as I can see, there is no phantom node or something like that at the sides.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Thanks for suggestion, I will try it.

Comment: The `text width=10cm` for the style `level1` enlarges your picture on the left and right side. So there is additional whitespace. Remove this setting for `level1` to get the desired result.

Comment: @esdd: That was it! Now the resulting image has the right width also whithin ther final document. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key `text width=10cm` in

```
level1/.style={
    minimum height=5mm,
    text width=10cm,
    text centered
},
```

enlarges the width of your picture. It seems to me that this key in not needed in the code. Remove this setting to get

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{rotating}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{10pt}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\xdefinecolor{midnightBlue}{RGB}{25,25,112}
\xdefinecolor{navy}{RGB}{0,0,128}
\xdefinecolor{fireblick}{RGB}{178,34,34}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=1, 
node distance=0mm,
desc/.style={
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    draw=black, 
    very thick,
     text centered,
    text width=7cm,
    minimum height=12mm,
    fill=midnightBlue!30,
    drop shadow
     },
hByte/.style={
    rectangle,
     rounded corners=1pt,
    draw=black, 
     thick,
    text centered,
     text width=0.6cm,
    minimum height=28mm,
     fill=midnightBlue!30,
    xshift=0.45cm,
    drop shadow
     },
Byte/.style={
    rectangle,
    rounded corners=1pt,
    draw=black, 
    thick,
    text centered,
    text width=0.6cm,
    minimum height=56mm,
    fill=midnightBlue!30,
    xshift=0.45cm,
    drop shadow
    },
qByte/.style={
    rectangle,
     rounded corners=1pt,
    draw=black, 
    thick,
    text centered,
    text width=2.6cm,
    minimum height=10mm,
    fill=midnightBlue!30,
    xshift=1.45cm,
    drop shadow
    },
it/.style={
    fill=blue!10
},
level1/.style={
    minimum height=5mm,
    %text width=10cm,% <- remove this
    text centered
},
every node/.style={font=\sffamily}
]
\node at (0cm,0cm) [] (base) {};
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
%draw level 1
\node at ($(base)+(-7cm,3cm)$) [desc, it, text width =4.7cm, xshift=2.5cm] (header) {...};
\node at ($(header.east)-(0cm,0cm)$) [desc, it, text width =6.7cm, xshift=3.5cm] (body) {timeSource};
\node at ($(body.east)-(0cm,0cm)$) [desc, it, text width =2.7cm, xshift=1.5cm] (tlv) {path trace TLV};
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
%draw segments
\def\arrowOffsetOne{0cm,2cm};
\def\arrowOffsetTwo{0cm,1cm};
\draw [darkgray,thin,<->] ($(header.north west)+(\arrowOffsetOne)$) -- ($(tlv.north east)+(\arrowOffsetOne)$) node [black,level1, midway, above=0.1cm] (frame) {Announce Nachricht};
\draw [darkgray,thin,<->] ($(header.north west)+(\arrowOffsetTwo)$) -- ($(header.north east)+(\arrowOffsetTwo)$) node [black,level1, midway, above=0.1cm] (headerLength) {29 Byte};
\draw [darkgray,thin,<->] ($(body.north west)+(\arrowOffsetTwo)$) -- ($(body.north east)+(\arrowOffsetTwo)$) node [black,level1, midway, above=0.1cm] (bodyLength) {1 Byte};
\draw [darkgray,thin,<->] ($(tlv.north west)+(\arrowOffsetTwo)$) -- ($(tlv.north east)+(\arrowOffsetTwo)$) node [black,level1, midway, above=0.1cm] (tlvLenght) {\textgreater 
    4 + 8N Byte};
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
%draw Header
\node at ($(base)+(-5cm,-3cm)$) [qByte, it, fill=orange!20] (node1) {tlvType};
\node at ($(node1.east)-(0.025cm,0cm)$) [qByte, it, fill=red!20] (node2) {lengthField};
\node at ($(node2.east)-(0.025cm,0cm)$) [qByte, it, fill=green!20] (lastnode) {pathSequence};
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
%draw separating lines
\draw [gray,dashed,thin] ($(header.north west)+(\arrowOffsetOne)+(0cm,1cm)$) -- (header.south west);
\draw [gray,dashed,thin] (tlv.south west) -- (node1.north west);

\draw [gray,dashed,thin] ($(body.north west)+(\arrowOffsetTwo)$) -- (body.south west);
\draw [gray,dashed,thin] ($(body.north east)+(\arrowOffsetTwo)$) -- (body.south east);
\draw [gray,dashed,thin] ($(tlv.north east)+(\arrowOffsetOne)+(0cm,1cm)$) -- (tlv.south east);
\draw [gray,dashed,thin] (tlv.south east) -- (lastnode.north east);

\draw [gray,dashed,thin] (node1.south west) -- ($(node1.south west)-(0,0.3)$);
\draw [gray,dashed,thin] (node1.south east) -- ($(node1.south east)-(0,0.3)$);
\draw [gray,dashed,thin] (node2.south east) -- ($(node2.south east)-(0,0.3)$);
\draw [gray,dashed,thin] (lastnode.south east) -- ($(lastnode.south east)-(0,0.3)$);

\node at ($(node1.south west)-(0.5,0.7)$) [black, level1] {Byte};

\draw [darkgray,thin,<->] ($(node1.south west)-(0,0.3)$) -- ($(node1.south east)-(0,0.3)$) node [black,level1, midway, below=0.1cm] {2};
\draw [darkgray,thin,<->] ($(node2.south west)-(0,0.2)$) -- ($(node2.south east)-(0,0.2)$) node [black,level1, midway, below=0.175cm] {2};
\draw [darkgray,thin,<->] ($(lastnode.south west)-(0,0.3)$) -- ($(lastnode.south east)-(0,0.3)$) node [black,level1, midway, below=0.1cm] {8N};
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```