# Figure is not correctly centered

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, vertical-alignment

I created a Figure consisting of 2 Tikz pictures. However, the two TikZ pictures are not correctly centered and are placed further on the right side of the page than they should be (see uploaded image).

The relevant part of my code looks as follows:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\sidesubfloat[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[framed,scale=0.5,rotate=90,yscale=-1]
[....]
\end{tikzpicture}} 
\sidesubfloat[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[framed,scale=0.5,rotate=90,yscale=-1]
[....]
\end{tikzpicture} }
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: just ignore the third figure below the other two^^

Comment: It seems to me that the first two figures together are wider than the `\textwidth`, so the second one sticks in the margin.

Comment: Add `\usepackage{showframe}` to check Piet van Oostrum's hypothesis.

Comment: you haven't shown your input, you haven't shown any over full warnings tex might have made, how do you expect anyone to debug this? (although you do have a word space to the left of the figures and not to the right, I agree with Piet it looks like the figures are too big.  try `height=.4\textwidth` instead of `scale=0.5`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You can't set the total width of `tikzpicture`s like that though, so perhaps `scale=0.4`.

Comment: You might need `begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,...` if you do not mind violating some typographical rules.

Comment: @Symbol1 How would `overlay` help here?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. With `\[\tikz[overlay]\node{\includegraphics{...}};\]` the figure will be centered no matter how wide it is.

Comment: @Symbol1 Well, yes, but what makes you think the only thing in the `tikzpicture`s is a `\node` with an image? And further it appears there are *two* `tikzpicture`s side by side with the second one sticking into the right margin, and `overlay` wont do any good in that case.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. In that case, put two graphics in one node or write`\tikz\path node[left]{...}node[right]{...};`. The point is that `\tikz[overlay]...` does a lot of job that used to be possible only if one plays with TeX primitives.

Comment: @Symbol1 Again, *what makes you think the only thing in the `tikzpicture`s is a `\node` with an image?* (You could be right, but from the information given it's not an assumption I would make.)

Comment: @aymi The best solution is probably to make the diagrams smaller, as mentioned above, but for centering `\makebox` or the `adjustbox` environment as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39436/586 would likely  do (i.e. add `\usepackage{adjustbox}` and put both subfloats between  `\begin{adjustbox}{center}` and `\end{adjustbox}`).

Comment: Did you figure this out? As David said in his comment, there really isn't enough information to accurately diagnose the problem, though the guesses above may well be correct.