# Lyx center a table larger than text column

Tags: tables, floats, horizontal-alignment, lyx, align

I am quite new to Lyx but I have a problem whose solution is impossible to find for me.

I have a table that is larger than the text column width but smaller that the entire page. I would like to center it so that is goes a bit on the page margin, but staying centered. I can't find a way, it always stays aligned with the left limit of the text, as in the following image.
[image]

I know I can resize the columns but I prefer not to shrink them any more.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi! Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show us your code, preferably only a minimal, yet compilable snippet so that we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: You should follow any of the guidelines presented in [Center figure that is wider than `\textwidth`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582/5764) or [How can I center a too wide table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39435/5764)

Answer (score 2):

As Werner mentions in a comment, there are several questions on how to do this with LaTeX code. Typically you would need to resort to TeX code insets, known as ERTs, to do the same in LyX. For example to use the `\makebox` trick, place the cursor right before the table, and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (Insert --> TeX code) to add a TeX code inset.

*Note*: the ERT has to be *inside* the float.

In this ERT, write

```
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
```

Then move the cursor to immediately after the table, and make a new ERT which contains only

```
}
```

Screenshot of how it may look in LyX, with output below:

[image]