# Make tabularx wider than textwidth .pt values

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I have a table

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Caption} 
\label{Lable} \\
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}  LLLL @{}}
\toprule
& \textbf{Col 1} & \textbf{Col 2} & \textbf{Col3} \\
\midrule
A & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
B & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
C & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\bottomrule
& 10 & 11 & 12
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Is there a way to make this table a certain amount wider than my `textwidth`, without taking it out of my textflow, using `.pt` values? I dont want the table to start on a new page/occupy a whole page after setting it wider than the `textwidth`.

Comment: Related: [How can I center a too wide table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39435/how-can-i-center-a-too-wide-table/39436#39436).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the `tabularx` environment into a `minipage` environment which a larger `\textwidth` then center or lap that `minipage`. The simplest way is to use the `adjustbox` package for that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for example text 

\begin{document}
\lipsum

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Caption}\label{Lable} 
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=18cm, center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} llll @{}}
\toprule
& \textbf{Col 1} & \textbf{Col 2} & \textbf{Col3} \\
\midrule
A & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
B & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
C & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\bottomrule
& 10 & 11 & 12
\end{tabularx}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Note that I changed the column-characters from `L` to `l` as I didn't had the `L` definition handy.

**Note:** If you just want to add some `pt` value to the current textwidth use e.g `minipage=\textwidth+20pt,center`. This adds 10pt on the left and right.

If you want the table to go 10pt into the *right* margin only use `minipage=\textwidth+10pt,left`.

If you want the table to go 10pt into the *left* margin only use `minipage=\textwidth+10pt,right`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

i guessing ...

[image]

red lines indicate page layout.

with use of `changepage` package:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-12pt}
\caption{Caption}
\label{Lable}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}  LLLL @{}}
\toprule
& \textbf{Col 1} & \textbf{Col 2} & \textbf{Col3} \\
\midrule
A & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
B & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
C & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\bottomrule
& 10 & 11 & 12
\end{tabularx}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}
```

or if you like that table spill out on both side text body:

[image]

for this you only change

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{-12pt}{-12pt}
```

you not provide complete small document, so i test above solution in mine "table testbad", which is not intended to show here ...

Answer (score 2):

I would go the simple route, `\makebox[\textwidth]{table of \textwidth + xpt}`. This will automatically center the table in addition to increasing the width by `xpt`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for example text 
\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Caption}\label{Lable} 
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\textwidth+50pt}{@{} llll @{}}
\toprule
& \textbf{Col 1} & \textbf{Col 2} & \textbf{Col3} \\
\midrule
A & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
B & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
C & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\bottomrule
& 10 & 11 & 12
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{table}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: this is what I'd do too:-)

Answer (score 1):

Should you have a tabularx breaking across pages, you can load the `ltablex` package, which combines `longtable` and `tabularx`, so that you can use the   longtable parameters within tabularx:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for example text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]
\begingroup
\setlength\LTleft{-40pt}
\setlength\LTright{-40pt}
\keepXColumns
\begin{tabularx}{1.2\textwidth}{@{}*{4}{X}@{}}
\caption{Caption}\label{Lable} \\
\toprule
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\tablename~\thetable: Caption (continued)}\smallskip \\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{r@{}}{to be continued}\\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
& \textbf{Col 1} & \textbf{Col 2} & \textbf{Col3} \\
\midrule
A & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
B & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
C & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
D & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
E = & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
F = & 16 & 17 & 18 \\
\midrule
T & 51 & 57 & 63
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]