# Set table width = `\paperwidth`

Tags: graphics, floats, width

I have a large table (with many columns), so that I decide to set its width = `\paperwidth`. I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
        \caption{something}\label{t:something}
        \centering  
        \noindent\resizebox{\paperwidth}{!}
        {
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            4 & 5 & 6 
        \end{tabular}
        }
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

The problem is, the table is shifted to the right (portion to the left is empty, whereas part of the table at right side is cropped). My question is, how to set it to center?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth Edit: or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39435/how-can-i-center-a-too-wide-table

Comment: Eventually, none of the solutions in the *original* question [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth] solves the problem. Requesting to reopen the question

Comment: Surely `\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\resizebox{\paperwidth}{!}{ ... }}` works?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Not really. I tried that before posting the question

Comment: What exactly did you try? That works perfectly fine for me. Alternatively, did you try the `adjustbox` method in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39436/? Edit 2: working example on Overleaf: https://v2.overleaf.com/read/rcxgcnxrcdsv

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I tried the same as in the Overleaf example (didn't work). I am using `llncs` document class -- possibly that creates the problem I think.

Comment: Then edit your question with an example that demonstrates `\makebox` not working. (It works fine also with `llncs` for me on Overleaf, see the link above again.)