# How can I get this table centered in the page?

Tags: tables

I have a table that I would like to be fully centered. I have tried using `\centering` but that hasn't worked.

My code is

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|p{1.4cm}|p{5cm}|p{1cm}|p{3.5cm}|}
        \hline
         More/Less(IV) of& Leads to & More/Less of (DV) & Due to & Reason\\
         \hline
         An increase in worldwide internet coverage & results in & an increase of video games with online functionality  & Due to & an increasing number of customers with internet \\
         \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

It ends up looking like this [image]

Comment: One problem is that your table is too wide for the page. Try making the columns smaller. Please provide a minimal working example for us to examine if that does not resolve your issue.

Comment: @schtandard oh sorry, I completely forgot, although Red-Cloud got it anyway.

Comment: Another relevant posting: [How can I center a too wide table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39435/5001)

Comment: @TomGionfriddo it is almost always better to make the table fit the specified text width, certainly if submitting to a journal making things stick in to the margin is usually not allowed, and using `\makebox[\textwidth]` will allow the table to be wider than the physical page so losing parts of the table with no warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
  ... your tabular code ...%
}
```