# I have been trying to center a table but I am unable to. my code is below, the \centering command doesn't seem to work

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

```latex
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}
\rowcolor[HTML]{656565} 
{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} Function}                                              & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} Input}                                            & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} Output}                                           & \multicolumn{3}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{656565}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} Physical principle}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} Embodiment} \\
                                                                             &                                                                         &                                                                         & action reaction                 & tension                  & friction                 & bolt                              \\
                                                                             & \multirow{-2}{*}{normal force}                                          & \multirow{-2}{*}{normal force}                                          & action reaction                 & friction                 & ...                      & screw                             \\
\multirow{-3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}connecting\\ parts\end{tabular}} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}normal force,\\ magnetic fields\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}normal force,\\ magnetic fields\end{tabular} & magnetism                       & ...                      & ...                      & magnets                          
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please extend your sniplet to a full but minimal exmaple that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: Besides that your table is much larger than the textwidth, so what exactly is LaTeX suppose to center this table incomparison to?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144) and/or [How can I center a too wide table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39435/134144)