# Aligning 12 figures in a grid - how to centre this structure when it is wider than the text width

Tags: subcaption, includegraphics

For clarity, I need the grid to be wider than the text width so that my figures are large enough to read.

I have tried this:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    
    \subcaptionbox{caption\label{1}}{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{figure}} &
    \subcaptionbox{caption\label{2}}{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{figure}} &
    \subcaptionbox{caption\label{3}}{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{figure}}\\
    
    \subcaptionbox{caption\label{1}}{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{figure}} &
    \subcaptionbox{caption\label{2}}{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{figure}} &
    \subcaptionbox{caption\label{3}}{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{figure}}\\

    \subcaptionbox{caption\label{1}}{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{figure}} &
    \subcaptionbox{caption\label{2}}{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{figure}} &
    \subcaptionbox{caption\label{3}}{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{figure}}\\
    
    \subcaptionbox{caption\label{1}}{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{figure}} &
    \subcaptionbox{caption\label{2}}{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{figure}} &
    \subcaptionbox{caption\label{3}}{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{figure}}\\

\end{tabular}
\caption{caption}
\label{label}
\end{figure}
```

But the whole structure is off centre slightly towards the right. How can I centre it?

Comment: Also related for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39435/how-can-i-center-a-too-wide-table or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth.

Comment: @Marijn The first solution works perfectly! Thank you.