# Changing the width of begin center

Tags: formatting

[image]

I am writing my Master's thesis and was wondering how I can write the introduction to every section like this. I have already gone through the other posts where they have discussed about how one can change the width of the 'begin center' part, but I was unable to use any of those techniques myself. Please let me know if you guys know some easier method. Thanks.

Comment: That is not centered text. It is text with different margins. It is basically what the `abstract` env does. In order to provide mode help we need to know what class and packages you are using (perhaps some of them already provide something usable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the layout used in the screenshot you posted by employing the `amsart` document class, using `\section` and `\subsection` directives, and employing a `quotation` environment. The `quotation` environment increases the widths of both the left and right margins or, put differently, reduces the value of `\textwidth`.

I would definitely not use a `center` environment, as you're not looking to center-set each line, are you?

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{8} % just for this example

\section{Intersection theory}

\begin{quotation}
\slshape % Employ slanted-roman font shape. If you prefer 
         % "regular" italics, use either '\itshape'  or '\em'.

\lipsum[2] % first para of filler text

\lipsum[2] % second para of filler text
\end{quotation}


\subsection{Chow groups} 

Having discussed the basics of scheme theory, we will now start 
with the foundations of intersection theory. The idea of 
intersection theory is the same as that of homology in \dots 
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems really easy, but when I tried it, there was a huge gap between the end quotation and the start of the subsection.

Comment: @RioDutta - So far, you have provided *exactly zero information* about your document setup -- other than the fact that you employ LaTeX to compile it. My example code managed to replicate the overall look of screenshot you provided rather well. However, your comment would make it appear that this "feat" is actually of little or no practical relevance to you. Hence, do please start to provide some relevant information about your document setup, starting with the document class you employ.

Comment: I am really sorry for providing such little information. As I have checked, this code seems to work on article class, but leaves the big gap in book class on Overleaf. Do you have any suggestions for the book class?

Comment: @RioDutta -- You still haven't provided much usable information about your document. Hence, all I can suggest you try is (a) shortening or lengthening the introduction, i.e., the material that's place in the `quotation` environment, and (b) issuing the command `\raggedbottom` in the preamble.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try `adjustbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=.7\textwidth,margin=0pt \smallskipamount,center}
    \itshape\lipsum[1]
\end{adjustbox}
\vspace{2em}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

This answer is adapted from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51664/234654).

[image: Result]