# How can I draw a line from margin to margin, if the text width has been adjusted using the changepage package?

Tags: indentation, margins, rules

I have a problem with drawing a line across the page (from margin to margin). I had to change default margins for title page (only for this page) and to do that I used `changepage` package.

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
...
...
...
\end{adjustwidth}
```

Everything looks great however lines which I draw using

```
\rule{\textwidth}{.1pt}
```

aren't drawn from margin to margin. The line starts at goo point however line clearly ends before text.
How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\linewidth` instead:

```
\rule{\linewidth}{.1pt}
```

To understand the difference, have a look at [Difference between \textwidth, \linewidth and \hsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/difference-between-textwidth-linewidth-and-hsize).

Example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{changepage}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
\blindtext[2]
\rule{\linewidth}{.1pt}
\end{adjustwidth}
\blindtext[2]
\rule{\linewidth}{.1pt}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: You beat me by 44 seconds. ;-)

Comment: @lockstep: just luck :-) so added some information, since there's the nice Q&A about the difference of those widths.