# How to avoid marginalnote in some sections

Tags: books

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=1.3cm,left=4cm,right=5cm,bindingoffset=0.25in,heightrounded,marginparwidth=4cm,marginparsep=3mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\colorlet{sectitlecolor}{red!60!black}
\colorlet{sectboxcolor}{cyan!30}
\colorlet{secnumcolor}{orange}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{sectitlecolor}}{\llap{\makebox[3em][l]{\colorbox{sectboxcolor}{\textcolor{secnumcolor}{\thesection}}}}}{0em}{} 
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\begin{document}
    \chapter{A test chapter}
    This is the first chapter
    \newgeometry{top=2cm,bottom=1.3cm,left=4cm,right=2cm}
    \section{First section}
    This is the first section without marginal note. 
    \restoregeometry 
    \section{Second section}
    This is the second section with marginal note.\reversemarginpar\marginnote{\textcolor{blue}{This is a margin note.}} 
    \newgeometry{top=2cm,bottom=1.3cm,left=4cm,right=2cm}
    \section{Third section}
    This is the third section without marginal note. 
    \restoregeometry 
    \section{Fourth section}
    This is the fourth section with marginal note.\reversemarginpar\marginnote{\textcolor{blue}{This is a margin note.}}
\end{document}
```

When I use the above, each section is printed in separate pages. I want this type of texts. Is it possible to print continuously, not in separate pages

Comment: The page breaks are the result of `\newgeometry`. What are you trying to achieve with those commands?

Comment: I want to use marginalnotes in few sections and not in the rest of the sections. I want to print exercise section in two column (without  marginalnote ). I don't know how to write the preamble.

Comment: Please see my answer below. Is it something like that what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry`are responsible for the page breaks. If, for some reason, you need to temporarily change the page layout (text width, margins, etc.) mid-page, then you can use the environments provided by the [`changepage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/changepage) package instead. According to comments, maybe this is what you want:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=1.3cm,left=4cm,right=5cm,bindingoffset=0.25in,heightrounded,marginparwidth=4cm,marginparsep=3mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multicol}

\colorlet{sectitlecolor}{red!60!black}
\colorlet{sectboxcolor}{cyan!30}
\colorlet{secnumcolor}{orange}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{sectitlecolor}}{\llap{\makebox[3em][l]{\colorbox{sectboxcolor}{\textcolor{secnumcolor}{\thesection}}}}}{0em}{} 

\begin{document}
    \chapter{A test chapter}
    This is the first chapter
    \section{First section}
    This is the first section without marginal note. 
    \section{Second section}
    This is the second section with marginal note.  \reversemarginpar\marginnote{\textcolor{blue}{This is a margin note.}} 
    \section{Third section}
    This is the third section without marginal note. 
    \section{Fourth section}
    This is the fourth section with marginal note.\reversemarginpar\marginnote{\textcolor{blue}{This is a margin note.}}
  \begin{multicols}{2}[\section{Exercises}]
  Some test text goes here to illustrate two-column mode and here we add some more words  test text goes here to illustrate two-column mode and here we add some more words  test text goes here to illustrate two-column mode and here we add some more words
  \end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I got the answer. In book class, how to increase the left side space in odd numbered page and right side space in even numbered page for the binding purpose. How to change the command in \usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=1.3cm,left=4cm,right=5cm,bindingoffset=0.25in,heightrounded,marginparwidth=4cm,marginparsep=3mm]{geometry}

Comment: @SGSekaran you already have `bindingoffset=0.25in`; you can increase the value, if required.

Comment: I think he needs temporally increase marginarea for the margin note and go back to normal textwidth size...I did this before ..dont remember...It is a package changepage  .. https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/changepage ...maybe this help http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27272/how-can-i-draw-a-line-from-margin-to-margin-if-the-text-width-has-been-adjusted

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili Perhaps, you're right. I added a remark about `changepage` in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @SGSekaran I updated my answer with new information that can be of interest for you.