# Text wrapping in multirow columns

Tags: tables, multirow

How do I make the long multirow cell wrap its text? Ideally I'd like to be able to specify a width for the entire column. The text should also be centered both vertically and horizontally.

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{looooooong cell} & cell1 & cell2 \\ \cline{2-3}
     & cell3 & cell4 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Just found a solution for a single cell (answered below). But I'm still wondering if there's any way to do it for an entire column. I'd rather not have to do this for each individual cell.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Actually just found a solution

```
\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{2cm}{\centering looooooong cell}}
```

works perfectly.

Answer (score 43):

`\multirow` would linewrap if you used the length of the box instead of * in

```
\multirow{3}{*}.
```

So,

```
\multirow{2}{2cm}{\centering looooooong cell}}
```

Comment: Note that `\linewidth` and the likes can also be used in the multirow length field.

Answer (score 7):

To expand your answer:
Use a paragraph box as in [Text wrap in tables (multirow package loaded)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36056/text-wrap-in-tables-multirow-package-loaded).  I've made the font larger for example purposes and added another row so you can see it's centered in both directions.

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\Huge
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox{4cm}{looooooong cell}} & cell1 & cell2 \\ \cline{2-3}
   & cell3 & cell4 \\ \cline{2-3}
   & cell5 & cell6 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me