# Scale figure to a percentage of \textwidth

Tags: graphics, margins, scaling

I would like to change my figure's width to a precentage of my `\textwidth`:

`\textwidth /2` would scale to 50% of the `\textwidth`.

What is the proper syntax (if any) to do this ?

Answer (score 226, accepted):

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \begin{document}
   \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{file}
 \end{document}
```

In some cases `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth` may be the better option. For example will it be the same as `\textwidth` in a single column document, but the same as `\columnwidth` in a two column document. `\linewidth` may also change in list environments, becoming smaller in nested lists.

As commented by Christian Lindig, see [Difference between \textwidth, \linewidth and \hsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/difference-between-textwidth-linewidth-and-hsize) for a discussion of this.

Comment: See also [the difference between `\textwidth`, `\linewidth` and `\hsize`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16942/3083). For these reasons you should use `\linewidth` because it works inside columns and minipages.

Comment: If used as-is, just remove the paragraph indentation to avoid a `\parindent` horizontal shift. I wouldn't change your MWE though, since the OP's usage may not require it (for example, within a `figure` environment).

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you for sharing the example