# Position of a figure within description items

Tags: graphics, lists, indentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Figure with caption within an itemize list not indenting correctly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54448/figure-with-caption-within-an-itemize-list-not-indenting-correctly)

I have the following code and I would like to position the figure based on the width of the description items.

```
\begin{description}    
  \item[Item One:] This is the text for the item one. 
    \begin{figure}[h]
      \centering
      \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{fig}
      \caption{The Figure}
    \end{figure}
\end{description}
```

Comment: did you have a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17085/15717) question and [another](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37793/15717)

Comment: Perhaps the answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54448/3954 can be useful in your situation.