# How can I make my image 0.5 cm wider than \textwidth?

Tags: width

A related question to my question is [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37790/scale-figure-to-a-percentage-of-textwidth), where it is discussed how to scale an object to a certain proportion of textwidth. However, what if I want to make an object 0.5 cm wider than textwidth?

I tried using `length = \textwidth + 0.5` doesn't seem to work

Comment: length = \dimexpr \textwidth+0.5cm could work (but as you didn't provide an example it is only a guess )

Comment: On which side image can spill out from text area?

Comment: Another simple way would be `\newlength{\mywidth}\setlength{\mywidth}{\textwidth}\addtolength{\mywidth}{0.5cm}`; but if you want the overflow to be balanced between left and right margins you may need to do more.

Answer (score 2):

With use of the `changepage` package is simple. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-5mm} % <--- new
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{adjustwidth}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{document}
```

[image: \lipsum[1][1-4]]

(redlines indicate (part of) page layout)

Comment: +1: So the change does not affect the complete page?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, no. Only the part inside `adjustwidth` environment. The `changepage`  package is to my opinion  very useful package. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

For example in OpTeX:

```
\line{\hss \picw=\dimexpr\hsize+0.5cm \inspic{image.jpg}\hss}
```