# Why is there an overfull box with \[ ... \]

Tags: math-mode, boxes

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\hsize 200pt

%A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet
%mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.

\[ e=mc^2 \]
\end{document}
```

gives me an overfull hbox:

```
Overfull \hbox (22.0021pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 9--9
[][]
```

using `$$...$$` instead of `\[...\]` works fine.

Using a soon-to-be-released tool for visual debugging shows me a strange box sticking out to the right:

[image: strangeboxstickingouttotheright]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because you changed the TeX primitive `\hsize` without telling LaTeX you had done so. You should change `\linewidth` preferably by using a LaTeX display environment construct that keeps all the LaTeX data consistent. Or for the whole document set `\textwidth` in the preamble.

Answer (score 13):

LaTeX's `\[` refers to `\linewidth`, not to `\hsize`. From `latex.ltx`:

```
\def\[{%
   \relax\ifmmode
      \@badmath
   \else
      \ifvmode
         \nointerlineskip
         \makebox[.6\linewidth]{}%
      \fi
      $$%%$$ BRACE MATCH HACK
   \fi
}
```

So you should change `\linewidth` instead, or redefine `\[` using `\hsize`. Try, and you will see the warning go away.

This shows again that mixing LaTeX and TeX code can sometimes be dangerous. If there's a LaTeX equivalent for a TeX command (or length), I would prefer the LaTeX command when writing LaTeX.

Regarding using the different widths, here's some further advice: [Difference between \textwidth, \linewidth and \hsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/difference-between-textwidth-linewidth-and-hsize).

Comment: Arrg, it's me, Mico, once again accidentally downvoting instead of upvoting an answer. Sorry! Please edit your answer a tiny bit to give me chance to change my vote. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I'll delete my comments in a few minutes as they're now irrelevant. :-)