# Customizing caption in side-by-side figures

Tags: floats, positioning, captions

How do I customize my caption that follows this [article's setting of the captions on page 26](https://kluedo.ub.uni-kl.de/volltexte/2009/2408/pdf/Braun09.pdf). The following is my attempt to do that, but still doesn't work. Obviously, what I want to achieve is to put the figures' names in small letter/alphabet((a) and (b)) for each of the pictures and there is another global caption below them which  is in number/figure. The provided link on the page 26 expresses this better.

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
 \begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
  \centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{figure/figA.png}}
  \caption{Figure on left side}\label{fig:figA}
 \end{minipage}
\hfill
 \begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
  \centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{figure/figB.png}}
  \caption{Figure on right side}\label{fig:figB}
 \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Or, am I using the wrong package?

Comment: Check my answer here:

[http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68001/side-by-side-minipage-figures][1]


  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68001/side-by-side-minipage-figures

Comment: You can try my answer and the examples provided here:
[http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68001/side-by-side-minipage-figures/193104#193104][1]


  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68001/side-by-side-minipage-figures/193104#193104

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can solve your problem by loading the `subcaption` package. (The `subcaption` package is incompatible with packages that provide similar functionality, such as `subfigure` and `subfloat`. If you use `subcaption`, be sure *not* to load one of these competing packages as well.) The `subcaption` package provides the environments `subfigure` and `subtable`, which take as their argument the desired *width* of the sub-figure/table in question. In the Minimum Working Example (MWE) below, I've set this width to `0.49\linewidth`, as you do in your example code. The MWE also illustrates how many may create cross-references to the entire float as well as to one or more of its components.

Note the use of the `\centering` commands inside the `subfigure` environments; it's preferable to use this command rather than `\centerline`. In addition, since I don't have access to the `.png` files you list in your code, I've loaded the `graphicx` package with the `demo` option -- this will create black "dummy" rectangles. In your "real" code, you should of course omit the `demo` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
   \begin{subfigure}{0.49\linewidth} \centering
     \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{figure/figA.png}
     \caption{Figure on left side}\label{fig:figA}
   \end{subfigure}
   \begin{subfigure}{0.49\linewidth} \centering
     \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{figure/figB.png}
     \caption{Figure on right side}\label{fig:figB}
   \end{subfigure}
\caption{Overall caption} \label{fig:twofigs}
\end{figure}

\noindent
Some cross-references: First, we refer to Figure~\ref{fig:twofigs}. 
Second, we can also refer to the component figures individually, 
viz., to Figures~\ref{fig:figA} and \ref{fig:figB}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum** For more information on what the parameters `\linewidth` and `\textwidth` do, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16956/5001) to a question that was posed some time ago, viz., [Difference between \textwidth, \linewidth and \hsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16942/5001).

Comment: Unfortunately, I received this error: Use of @subfloat doesn't match its definition \begin{subfigure}{

Comment: It now works out of the box after disabling a package called "subfigure"..They might clash before..Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: The `subcaption` and `subfigure` packages are NOT compatible. (You hadn't mentioned in your question that you were loading the `subfigure` package.) I will note this conflict in the text above.

Comment: One last question perhaps, what is \linewidth parameter for? Is it for the width of each of sub-image?

Comment: OK, I'll add some information about the parameter `\linewidth` to the answer.

Comment: Rather than using `.49\linewidth` you can use `.5\linewidth` provided that you put a `%` after the first `\end{subfigure}`

Comment: @Mico: How do I fix my problem of having the second figure's caption is not aligned with the first one? This happens when I change different figure..

Comment: @Shah: I suggest you post a new question to raise this follow-up concern. You may want to explain in which sense(s) the two subfigures don't line up with each other. E.g., do they differ in their heights, their widths, or both?

Comment: @Mico:Thanks a lot for your suggestion. But I think, it's far much easier to manipulate the images to be at the same size using GIMP, or the like than tweaking the latex..Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: @Mico, Hi, this worked nicely. But the captions are aligned. I want to place the `captions` along same the horizontal level below the figures. Any help

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR - Please clarify what you mean by "But the captions are aligned."

Comment: @Mico, I mean the captions `(a) Figure on left side` and `(b) Figure on right side` are not aligned along same horizontal level. One is displaying up while another is displaying little bit down

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR - Have you tried replacing both instances of `\begin{subfigure}{0.49\linewidth}` with `\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\linewidth}`?

Comment: @Mico, thanks. It worked. Now I want to remove the `overall caption`, instead I want Figure numbering replacing `(a)` and `(b)` on the subcaptions. How to do it ?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR - I'm afraid I've lost track of your setup. Please post a *new* query in which you provide all oertinent information.

Comment: @Mico, It is alright. Thank you very much so far helping

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a subfloat. Take a look [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats)

Comment: It complaints somehow, is it not meant to be used with .png imgage format?

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate a bit? Just a link doesn't add much value to the site, even if the external text may help the OP.

Comment: @Dennis: Thanks a lot..this one also works, after disabling subfigure package.

Answer (score 2):

For putting figures side by side you can try this one. (captions and everything are handled automatically and you may use more or less number of figures: 2, 3, 4, etc.):

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\subfigure[Subfigure 1 title]{
    \rule{2.8cm}{2cm}
    \label{fig:subfig1}
}
\subfigure[Subfigure 2 title]{
    \rule{2.8cm}{2cm}
\label{fig:subfig2}
}
\subfigure[Subfigure 3 title]{
    \rule{2.8cm}{2cm}
    \label{fig:subfig3}
}
\subfigure[Subfigure 4 title]{
    \rule{2.8cm}{2cm}
    \label{fig:subfig4}
}
\caption[Optional caption for list of figures]{General Caption of subfigures 1-4}
\label{fig:subfigureExample1}
\end{figure}

Reference to figure1:
    \ref{fig:subfigureExample1} 
and 
    \ref{fig:subfig4}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
And the referencing:
```

[image]

Or this one (you have to provide images subfig5.jpg to subfig8.jpg):

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\subfigure[Subfigure 5 title]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth, keepaspectratio]{subfig5.jpg}
    \label{fig:subfig5}
}
\subfigure[Subfigure 6 title]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth, keepaspectratio]{subfig6.jpg}       
    \label{fig:subfig6}
}
\subfigure[Subfigure 7 title]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth, keepaspectratio]{subfig7.jpg}    
    \label{fig:subfig7}
}
\subfigure[Subfigure 8 title]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth, keepaspectratio]{subfig8.jpg}    
    \label{fig:subfig8}
}
\caption[Optional caption for list of figures 5-8]{General Caption of subfigures 5-8}
\label{fig:subfigureExample2}
\end{figure}

Reference to figure:
    \ref{fig:subfigureExample2} 
and 
    \ref{fig:subfig6}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
And the referencing:
```

[image]

Hint: "Subfigure" package may be old, but does anything automatically. I tried several options and found it the most useful one.