# side by side minipage figures

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage

I have this code where the part marked `A` is the same as the part marked `B` except that `.4` in `A` is `.45` in `B`.  Even though they are so similar the first one puts the images side by side with the rightmost one flush right but the second one does not do that.  I don't understand why there is a difference.  Could someone explain that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{center} 
\noindent\colorbox{blue}{\parbox[t][0.5cm][c]{\textwidth}{\bfseries{HEADER}}}
\end{center} 

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

%A
\noindent\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=2in]{elephant}
Some text.
\end{minipage} 
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=2in]{elephant}
Some more text.
\end{minipage}

\end{minipage}

\vspace{5ex}

%B
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=2in]{elephant}
Some text.
\end{minipage} 
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=2in]{elephant}
Some more text.
\end{minipage}

\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: screenshot]

Creative commons info on elephant image is [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/sarah_mccans/293290118/sizes/n/in/photostream/)

Comment: In addition to what @Gonzalo said, note that you have a word space (as well as the `\hfill` between the two minipages, because of a missing `%` after the `\end{minipage}` This doesn't matter if you do want the gap down the middle but if you try to increase the width up towards `0.5\textwidth` you will find that you can not fit in the two minipages side by side without removing the word space between them.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  It seems strange that one needs a `%` after `end{minipage}` but not after `\hfill` .  There seem so many small points like this that are useful but difficult to really know.  Since its difficult to know when you really need `%` and when not it seems safer to use `%` liberally -- although its a bit disappointing that one must program defensively like this because the language itself is too difficult to really understand.

Comment: white space after command names is always ignored (it is just used to terminate the command) so the linebreak after `\hfill` contributes nothing. after a `}` there is no automatic white space removal. It os a pain though which is why the LaTeX3 proposed programming setup makes all white space ignored (and you have to explicitly use `~` to get a space anywhere.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In A) you declare a width of `.4\textwidth` for the `minibox`es and a width of `2in` for the images, but `2in > .4`\textwidth (with default margins); your images in fact are wider that the space reserved for them and the images overflow over the right margin (check this using the `draft` class option and looking at the `.log` file).

In B) the images have now enough space since `2in <.45\textwidth`, the `minipage`s fill the text width but not the images; the image in the second minipage is typeset starting the minipage so you will have a white space of width `.45\textwidth-2in` (you can verify this using `\fbox` around each `minipage` setting `\fboxsep` to `0pt`).

In your header you are not taking into account `\fboxsep` (the spacing between the box and its contents) and this will cause a overfull box (the width for the `\parbox` must be `\textwidth-2\fboxsep`).

In the following code I used the `draft` class option (overfull `\hbox`es will be signaled using a black rule) and enclosed the minipages using a red frame so you can see what is really going on:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\Mybox[1]{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\fcolorbox{red}{white}{#1}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center} 
\noindent\colorbox{blue}{\parbox[t][0.5cm][c]{\textwidth}{\bfseries{HEADER}}}
\end{center} 

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

%A
\noindent\Mybox{\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=2in]{elephant}
Some text.
\end{minipage}} 
\hfill
\Mybox{\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=2in]{elephant}
Some more text.
\end{minipage}}

\end{minipage}

\vspace{5ex}

%B
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

\noindent\Mybox{\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=2in]{elephant}
Some text.
\end{minipage}} 
\hfill
\Mybox{\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=2in]{elephant}
Some more text.
\end{minipage}}

\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]

Here's a modified version of your code; using `width=\linewidth` guarantees that the images will take exactly the available space inside the `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{center} 
\colorbox{blue}{\parbox[t][0.5cm][c]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\bfseries{HEADER}}}
\end{center} 

\lipsum[2]

\noindent\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{elephant}
Some text.
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{elephant}
Some more text.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The `\fboxsep` part seems particularly tricky.  Now that you explained it I think I will just set it to zero: `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}`. I also had to look up the difference between `\linewidth` and `\textwidth` and found it here: http://www.public.asu.edu/~rjansen/latexdoc/textwidth.html

Answer (score 1):

For putting figures side by side you can try this one (everything is handled automatically and you may use more or less number of figures: 2, 3, 4, etc.):

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\subfigure[Subfigure 1 title]{
    \rule{2.8cm}{2cm}
    \label{fig:subfig1}
}
\subfigure[Subfigure 2 title]{
    \rule{2.8cm}{2cm}
\label{fig:subfig2}
}
\subfigure[Subfigure 3 title]{
    \rule{2.8cm}{2cm}
    \label{fig:subfig3}
}
\subfigure[Subfigure 4 title]{
    \rule{2.8cm}{2cm}
    \label{fig:subfig4}
}
\caption[Optional caption for list of figures]{General Caption of subfigures 1-4}
\label{fig:subfigureExample1}
\end{figure}

Reference to figure1:
    \ref{fig:subfigureExample1} 
and 
    \ref{fig:subfig4}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
And the referencing:
```

[image]

Or this one (you have to provide images subfig5.jpg to subfig8.jpg):

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\subfigure[Subfigure 5 title]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth, keepaspectratio]{subfig5.jpg}
    \label{fig:subfig5}
}
\subfigure[Subfigure 6 title]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth, keepaspectratio]{subfig6.jpg}       
    \label{fig:subfig6}
}
\subfigure[Subfigure 7 title]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth, keepaspectratio]{subfig7.jpg}    
    \label{fig:subfig7}
}
\subfigure[Subfigure 8 title]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth, keepaspectratio]{subfig8.jpg}    
    \label{fig:subfig8}
}
\caption[Optional caption for list of figures 5-8]{General Caption of subfigures 5-8}
\label{fig:subfigureExample2}
\end{figure}

Reference to figure:
    \ref{fig:subfigureExample2} 
and 
    \ref{fig:subfig6}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
And the referencing:
```

[image]

Hint: "Subfigure" package may be old, but does anything automatically. I tried several options and found it the most useful one.

Comment: The problem is that `subfigure` is not only old but an *obsolete* package which shouldn't be used anymore; one should use `subfig` or `subcaption` instead. There are already plenty examples using subcaption or subfig (for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37597/3954), so I would suggest you to consider rewriting the answer so that it provides new information.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Gonzalo. Added another answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like using subfigure, then use "caption" and "subcaption":

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}  
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth, keepaspectratio]
        {frog.jpg}
        \caption{Subfigure 1 title}\label{fig:subfig1}      
    \end{subfigure}
    \quad
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth, keepaspectratio]
        {frog.jpg}
        \caption{Subfigure 2 title}\label{fig:subfig2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth, keepaspectratio]
        {frog.jpg}
        \caption{Subfigure 3 title}\label{fig:subfig3}      
    \end{subfigure}
    \quad
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth, keepaspectratio]
        {frog.jpg}
        \caption{Subfigure 4 title}\label{fig:subfig4}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{General Caption of subfigures 1-4}\label{fig:subfigureExample1}
\end{figure}    

Testing Reference to figure:
Figure \ref{fig:subfigureExample1} and Figure \ref{fig:subfig4}.

\end{document}
```

[image]