# how to handle corrupted graphics file

Tags: graphics

I am generating a latex file with many `\includegraphics` commands from a program.  The image files change from run to run.  The latex file might, for example, look like the one in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68087/side-by-side-minipages-with-keepaspectratio-true).  Occasionally an image file that I receive is corrupted.  I can eliminate nearly all such situations by checking the size of the image file and emitting some vertical space instead of the `\includegraphics` command should the the image file be too small to reasonably be the sort of image I am expecting; however, a very small number of corrupted image files are larger.  In that case pdflatex stops with an error message.  All my image files are `.jpg` files.  I believe that [jpegtran](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_jpegtran.htm) on UNIX will fix most of these and I could pass every jpeg through that but I am concerned about the impact on runtime if I do that and also there could still be a very few that that does not address. Is there a way to handle this? Basically I need something like: "include a jpg file using `includegraphics` without generating an error and if that fails then emit some vertical space otherwise the `includegraphics` can stand".

Comment: Are your images all in the same folder? I would run some external script that can pick up the corrupted images and replace them with some standard faulty image (like [`mwe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe)'s `example-image-a`).

Comment: I could run `jpegtran` on them all in advance but its not really that convenient and also I am not sure that that would necessarily catch them all although it probably would catch most. I would prefer if all this were self contained in the report so I don't have to start messing with external processes.

Comment: TeX can't even adequately handle bounding box issues, so I don't think it would be able to detect corrupted JPGs internally/at compile time (let alone efficiently).

Comment: So there is no try...catch processing possible in tex?  Seems like a serious omission.

Comment: Perhaps related: [Trapping LaTeX error/warning](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26460/5764)

Comment: You could write a wrapper macro around `\includegraphics` which uses a local `\nonstopmode` to make LaTeX keep going after an error. I'm not 100% sure if this will stop all driver errors as well.

Comment: @Martin, Under Linux I tried running `\documentclass{article} \nonstopmode \usepackage{graphicx} \begin{document} \includegraphics{corrupt.jpg} \end{document}` with `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode mytest.tex`but it still stopped.  The first line of output of `pdflatex --version` gives `pdfeTeX 3.141592-1.21a-2.2 (Web2C 7.5.4)`; however, the same procedure did work under Windows Vista.  In that case `pdflatex --version` gives `MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.8.3563 (1.40.10) (MiKTeX 2.8)`  .

Comment: I guess that's a pdftex issue, i.e. in the PDF part, not in the TeX part. Then it wouldn't technically be an TeX error, but a PDF format one. It would help if you post the full error message.

Comment: @Martin, The error message was: `Error: pdflatex (file corrupt.jpg): reading JPEG image failed
 ==> Fatal error occurred, the output PDF file is not finished!
` .  Its as if `nonstopmode` had not been turned on.

Comment: Like I feared. That's a PDF specific error which isn't handled by the normal TeX layers at all. I don't think you can do anything about this from inside TeX.

Comment: @Martin, Thanks.  I have not tried this but this user found that changing versions fixed it: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=77211

Comment: @MartinScharrer Can you give an answer (in the negative, I fear)?

Comment: @egreg: Now done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error you get:

```
Error: pdflatex (file corrupt.jpg): reading JPEG image failed 
==> Fatal error occurred, the output PDF file is not finished!
```

Even with `nonstopmode` active indicates to me that this is a pdfTeX specific issue which occurs in the special PDF-related code of the binary which is responsible for reading JPEG files and not a real TeX error.

Therefore there seems to be nothing you can do in (La)TeX itself. If you can't manually sort out the corrupted files then I would try to write a script which compiles a small test document for each image and checks if the compilation was successful.