# An image side by side in latex

Tags: graphics, floats

I would like to have two figures side by side in my document. I found an example on here with the following code

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{image}
\captionof{figure}{A figure}
\label{fig: test1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{image}
\captionof{figure}{Another figure}
\label{fig: test2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

However when I try to compile it it comes up with the following errors:

> template.tex  error  line 195   Argument of \caption@ydblarg has an
>   extra } \end{figure}
>
> template.tex  error  line 195   Paragraph ended before \caption
>   @ydblarg was complete \end{figure}

How can I fix this to make it work?

Comment: Please edit your question so that it includes a complete example that reproduces the problem. I can't see anything wrong in the fragment you have posted.

Comment: That suggests you have a missing `{` in the caption argument the fragment you posted looks OK but it isnt the code that made that error. Please always post _complete_ small documents that reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think we've had this question quite a few times before, e.g: [LaTeX figures side by side](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37581), [Two figures side by side](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5769)

Answer (score 1):

try to use `subfigure` instead of `minipage`.

How about this code :

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pic1}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pic2}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{two pictures side by side}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0):

This compiles fine for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{image}
\captionof{figure}{A figure}
\label{fig: test1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{image}
\captionof{figure}{Another figure}
\label{fig: test2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try my answer and the examples provided here:

[side by side minipage figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68001/side-by-side-minipage-figures/193104#193104)