# Vertically aligning captions in side-by-side figures

Tags: floats, captions, vertical-alignment, subfloats

I'd like to put two side-by-side figures with two different captions. I used this:

```
\begin{figure}[h!tbp]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/fig1.jpg}
    \caption{Caption 1.}
    \label{fig1}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/fig2.png}
    \caption{Caption 2.}
    \label{fig2}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

However, I suppose that because the figures' heights are different, the captions aren't vertically aligned (one is above the other). I would like to lower the upper one till it reaches the bottom one, creating a blank space between the figure and its caption. Is there a quick fix?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/two-figures-side-by-side. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: Maybe also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45991/customizing-caption-in-side-by-side-figures

Answer (score 4):

Just make two rows, one for images, one for captions

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/fig1.jpg}
    \end{minipage}%%%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/fig2.png}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
    \caption{Caption 1.}
    \label{fig1}
    \end{minipage}%%%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
    \caption{Caption 2.}
    \label{fig2}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```