# Putting figures side-by-side align top of image and top of caption

Tags: subfloats, adjustbox

I know there are a ton of questions about this but I seem to not be able to find want I want. I want to pictures side by side with the picture aligned to the top and the caption to the bottom. I wanted to follow [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290285), but the minipage position parameter doesn't seem to work.

MWE:

```
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}
    \end{minipage}%%%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
    \caption{Caption 1.}
    \label{fig1}
    \end{minipage}%%%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
    \caption{Caption 2.}
    \label{fig2}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
```

This gives me: [image]

independent of whether I have a b's or t's in the first two minipages.

Want I would want is: [image]

No matter what I do the second image doesn't want to move up. I have tried adding a vertical space after the second image and that does work but then I have to guess the distance...

Comment: You should take a look at the `floatrow` package.

Answer (score 1):

Using the package `adjustbox` is a possibility. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34200/161015 and the nice explanation https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34172/161015

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox} % added <<<<<

\begin{document}    
    
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth} % changed <<<<
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}
    \end{minipage}}%%%
    \hfill  
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}% changed <<<<
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}
        \vfill
    \end{minipage}} 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
        \caption{Caption 1.}
        \label{fig1}
    \end{minipage}%%%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
        \caption{Caption 2.}
        \label{fig2}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}    
    
\end{document
```

Comment: If you load the `adjustbox` package with the `export` option, you can add `valign=t` as an option to `\includegraphics` in order to get the same output.