# How to plot the 3D graph of the following three inequalities in latex (e.g., tikz/pgf)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-3dplot

How to plot the 3D graph of the following three inequalities in latex (tikz/pgf) ?

z <= x+y+1,

z <= 4x,

z <= 5y.

---

**My attempt:**

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
            \addplot3 [
            domain=-5:20,
            domain y = -3:10,
            samples = 20,
            samples y = 8,
            surf] {x+y+1};
            \addplot3[domain=-5:20,
            domain y = -3:10,
            samples = 20,
            samples y = 8,
            surf, opacity=0.25]{4*x};
            \addplot3[domain=-5:20,
            domain y = -3:10,
            samples = 20,
            samples y = 8,
            surf, opacity=0.25]{5*y};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{document}
```

The above Latex code produces the above figure:
[image]

But the above  graph is not clear, the intersecting line of the three half-planes are not clear.

Any help to draw clear image with clear intersection.

Any help both with the 3D graph of the given 3 inequalities.

Thanks

**Edit:**

The 2D projection of the above 3 inequalities becomes:

[image]

and this is justified by the answer of @Juan Castaño.

Comment: The 3D question seems a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109196/intersecting-planes-not-shown-correctly-with-tikz

Comment: @Fran, yes, i have seen that question. But the answer are sufficient. I need to display the intersecting lines clearly

Comment: Always post complete compilable code starting with `\documentclass{..` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: @hpekristiansen, thanks. I did it now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not very difficult to draw with `tikz` (and it looks better than with `pgfplots` in this case IMHO). The main problem is a maths problem: finding all the intersection points and lines. And then you have to split the planes and order each piece to have the visibility right.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset
{%
  plane 1/.style={thick,blue,fill=cyan!20,fill opacity=0.9},            % z=x+y+1
  plane 2/.style={thick,green!40!black,fill=green!20,fill opacity=0.9}, % z=4x
  plane 3/.style={thick,brown,fill=yellow!20,fill opacity=0.9},         % z=5y
  inter/.style  ={thick,red},                                           % intersection lines
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[%
  x={(-0.4cm,-0.2cm)},y={(0.8cm,-0.3cm)},z={(0cm,0.4cm)},%
  line cap=round,line join=round%
]
% z=x+y+1
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0,1);
\coordinate (A2) at (4,0,5);
\coordinate (A3) at (4,4,9);
\coordinate (A4) at (0,4,5);
% z=4x
\coordinate (O)  at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (B2) at (4,0,16);
\coordinate (B3) at (4,4,16);
\coordinate (B4) at (0,4,0);
% z=5y
\coordinate (C2) at (4,0,0);
\coordinate (C3) at (4,4,20);
\coordinate (C4) at (0,4,20);
% intersection points
\coordinate (P)  at (4,3.2,16);
\coordinate (Q)  at (4,1.25,6.25);
\coordinate (R)  at (5/11,4/11,20/11);
\coordinate (S)  at (5/3,4,20/3);
\coordinate (T)  at (0,0.25,1.25);
\coordinate (U)  at (1/3,0,4/3);
% projection points
\coordinate (V)  at (4,4,0);
\coordinate (W)  at (5/11,4/11,0);
\coordinate (X)  at (4,1.25,0);
\coordinate (Y)  at (5/3,4,0);
% axes and dashed lines
\draw[dashed] (4,0,0) -- (B2);
\draw[dashed] (0,4,0) -- (C4);
\draw[thick,-latex] (O) -- (5,0,0)  node [left]  {$x$};
\draw[thick,-latex] (O) -- (0,5,0)  node [right] {$y$};
\draw[thick,-latex] (O) -- (0,0,15) node [above] {$z$};
% planes and intersection lines
\draw[plane 1] (A1) -- (U)  -- (R)  -- (T)  -- cycle;
\draw[plane 3] (O)  -- (P)  -- (C3) -- (C4) -- cycle;
\draw[plane 1] (T)  -- (A4) -- (S)  -- (R)  -- cycle;
\draw[plane 2] (O)  -- (B2) -- (B3) -- (B4) -- cycle;
\draw[plane 1] (U)  -- (A2) -- (Q)  -- (R)  -- cycle;
\draw[plane 3] (O)  -- (C2) -- (C3) -- (P)  -- cycle;
\draw[inter]   (O)  -- (P);
\draw[plane 1] (Q)  -- (R)  -- (S)  -- (A3) -- cycle;
\draw[inter]   (Q)  -- (R)  -- (S);
% projection
\draw[fill=gray!20] (W) -- (Y)  -- (V) -- (X)  -- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray!30] (O) -- (B4) -- (Y) -- (W)  -- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray!40] (O) -- (W)  -- (X) -- (C2) -- cycle;
% more dashed lines
\draw[dashed] (V) -- (C3);
\draw[dashed] (W) -- (R);
\draw[dashed] (X) -- (Q);
\draw[dashed] (Y) -- (S);
% labels
\node[blue]           at (A4) [right] {$z=x+y+1$};
\node[green!40!black] at (B2) [above] {$z=4x$};
\node[brown]          at (C4) [above] {$z=5y$};
\fill[red] (R) circle (1pt) node [below right] {$\left(\frac{5}{11},\frac{4}{11},\frac{20}{11}\right)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit 1:** This is the 2D projection. It's essentially the same code from above (labeled 'projection') but removing the planes, lines and the third coordinate in each point.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset
{%
  plane 1/.style={fill=cyan!20  ,fill opacity=0.9}, % z=x+y+1
  plane 2/.style={fill=green!20 ,fill opacity=0.9}, % z=4x
  plane 3/.style={fill=yellow!20,fill opacity=0.9}, % z=5y
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,line cap=round,line join=round]
% z=4x
\coordinate (O)  at (0,0);
\coordinate (B4) at (0,4);
% z=5y
\coordinate (C2) at (4,0);
% projection points
\coordinate (V)  at (4,4);
\coordinate (W)  at (5/11,4/11);
\coordinate (X)  at (4,1.25);
\coordinate (Y)  at (5/3,4);
% axes
\draw[thick,-latex] (O) -- (5,0) node [right] {$x$};
\draw[thick,-latex] (O) -- (0,5) node [above] {$y$};
% projection
\draw[plane 1] (W) -- (Y)  -- (V) -- (X)  -- cycle;
\draw[plane 2] (O) -- (B4) -- (Y) -- (W)  -- cycle;
\draw[plane 3] (O) -- (W)  -- (X) -- (C2) -- cycle;
% labels
\node at (2.5,2.5) {$z=x+y+1$};
\node at (0.7,3.5) {$z=4x$};
\node at (3  ,0.5) {$z=5y$};
\fill[red] (W) circle (1pt) node [above right] {$\left(\frac{5}{11},\frac{4}{11},\frac{20}{11}\right)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit 2:** following the OP comments I joined the two pictures using subcaptions. Depending of the document geometry it probably will need changes of scales or widths.

Sorry for the duplicated code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage   {caption}
\usepackage   {lipsum}    % dummy text
\usepackage   {showframe} % just for the example
\usepackage   {tikz}

\tikzset
{%
  plane 1/.style={thick,blue,fill=cyan!20,fill opacity=0.9},            % z=x+y+1
  plane 2/.style={thick,green!40!black,fill=green!20,fill opacity=0.9}, % z=4x
  plane 3/.style={thick,brown,fill=yellow!20,fill opacity=0.9},         % z=5y
  inter/.style  ={thick,red},                                           % intersection lines
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h]\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.54\textwidth}\centering % b = bottom alignment
\begin{tikzpicture}
[%
  scale=0.6, % <-- added
  x={(-0.4cm,-0.2cm)},y={(0.8cm,-0.3cm)},z={(0cm,0.4cm)},%
  line cap=round,line join=round%
]
% z=x+y+1
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0,1);
\coordinate (A2) at (4,0,5);
\coordinate (A3) at (4,4,9);
\coordinate (A4) at (0,4,5);
% z=4x
\coordinate (O)  at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (B2) at (4,0,16);
\coordinate (B3) at (4,4,16);
\coordinate (B4) at (0,4,0);
% z=5y
\coordinate (C2) at (4,0,0);
\coordinate (C3) at (4,4,20);
\coordinate (C4) at (0,4,20);
% intersection points
\coordinate (P)  at (4,3.2,16);
\coordinate (Q)  at (4,1.25,6.25);
\coordinate (R)  at (5/11,4/11,20/11);
\coordinate (S)  at (5/3,4,20/3);
\coordinate (T)  at (0,0.25,1.25);
\coordinate (U)  at (1/3,0,4/3);
% projection points
\coordinate (V)  at (4,4,0);
\coordinate (W)  at (5/11,4/11,0);
\coordinate (X)  at (4,1.25,0);
\coordinate (Y)  at (5/3,4,0);
% axes and dashed lines
\draw[dashed] (4,0,0) -- (B2);
\draw[dashed] (0,4,0) -- (C4);
\draw[thick,-latex] (O) -- (5,0,0)  node [left]  {$x$};
\draw[thick,-latex] (O) -- (0,5,0)  node [right] {$y$};
\draw[thick,-latex] (O) -- (0,0,15) node [above] {$z$};
% planes and intersection lines
\draw[plane 1] (A1) -- (U)  -- (R)  -- (T)  -- cycle;
\draw[plane 3] (O)  -- (P)  -- (C3) -- (C4) -- cycle;
\draw[plane 1] (T)  -- (A4) -- (S)  -- (R)  -- cycle;
\draw[plane 2] (O)  -- (B2) -- (B3) -- (B4) -- cycle;
\draw[plane 1] (U)  -- (A2) -- (Q)  -- (R)  -- cycle;
\draw[plane 3] (O)  -- (C2) -- (C3) -- (P)  -- cycle;
\draw[inter]   (O)  -- (P);
\draw[plane 1] (Q)  -- (R)  -- (S)  -- (A3) -- cycle;
\draw[inter]   (Q)  -- (R)  -- (S);
% projection
\draw[fill=gray!20] (W) -- (Y)  -- (V) -- (X)  -- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray!30] (O) -- (B4) -- (Y) -- (W)  -- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray!40] (O) -- (W)  -- (X) -- (C2) -- cycle;
% more dashed lines
\draw[dashed] (V) -- (C3);
\draw[dashed] (W) -- (R);
\draw[dashed] (X) -- (Q);
\draw[dashed] (Y) -- (S);
% labels
\node[blue]           at (A4) [right] {$z=x+y+1$};
\node[green!40!black] at (B2) [above] {$z=4x$};
\node[brown]          at (C4) [above] {$z=5y$};
\fill[red] (R) circle (1pt) node [below right] {$\left(\frac{5}{11},\frac{4}{11},\frac{20}{11}\right)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Subpicture 1}\label{fig:figA}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.44\textwidth}\centering % b = bottom alignment
\begin{tikzpicture}
[%
  scale=0.8, % <-- added
  thick,line cap=round,line join=round
]
% z=4x
\coordinate (O)  at (0,0);
\coordinate (B4) at (0,4);
% z=5y
\coordinate (C2) at (4,0);
% projection points
\coordinate (V)  at (4,4);
\coordinate (W)  at (5/11,4/11);
\coordinate (X)  at (4,1.25);
\coordinate (Y)  at (5/3,4);
% axes
\draw[thick,-latex] (O) -- (5,0) node [right] {$x$};
\draw[thick,-latex] (O) -- (0,5) node [above] {$y$};
% projection
\draw[plane 1] (W) -- (Y)  -- (V) -- (X)  -- cycle;
\draw[plane 2] (O) -- (B4) -- (Y) -- (W)  -- cycle;
\draw[plane 3] (O) -- (W)  -- (X) -- (C2) -- cycle;
% labels
\node at (2.6,2.5) {$z=x+y+1$}; % <-- changed
\node at (0.7,3.5) {$z=4x$};
\node at (3  ,0.3) {$z=5y$};    % <-- changed
\fill[red] (W) circle (1pt) node [above right] {$\left(\frac{5}{11},\frac{4}{11},\frac{20}{11}\right)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Subpicture 1}\label{fig:figB}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I think the three planes meet at the point (5/11,4/11,9/11), which is the point where the two red lines and one yellow line meet. Am I right ?

Comment: can you please help with the 2D projection of the above graph in z=0 plane ? As you see in the Edit, that the 2D projection matches with your plot in xy-plane.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR, the intersection point is, if I'm not wrong, (5/11,4/11,20/11) which is indeed where the red lines meet. For the other comment, you can draw the 2D projection reusing the code thus labeled. You only need to remove the third coordinate of each point W,Y,V,X,...

Comment: ok, I will try. But can you label the point where the red lines meet by pointing the coordinates there ?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR, I just made an edit with the 2D projection and the intersection point.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much. You plotted exactly what I was expecting.

Comment: Castano, I wish to place the two figures above side-by-side. I have used `\begin{center} (1st tikz code) \qquad (2nd Tikz code) \end{center}`. This places the above two figures side by side by using the command `\qquad`. But how to write captions below each figure ? Can you demonstrate the way in form of an answer ?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR, you can do something like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/612112/side-by-side-pictures-on-a-landscape-page. Put the `tikzpicture`s instead of the `\includegrahics...`.

Comment: But I am not including graphics, I am plotting with Tikz. So `\includegraphics` would not help. I have got something here-https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45991/customizing-caption-in-side-by-side-figures  Which I have tried to use in the following answer.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR, just change `\includegraphics...` for `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: Can you please check the following code in my own answer ? This is giving side by side figures but the captions levels are not in same horizontal lines. Can you please run it ? I just need to get the caption levels along same horizontal lines

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR, I made an edit. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes that helps. But I don;t need the `overall caption` instead I want to get numerical numberings in place of `(a)` and `(b)` e.g., `Figure 1` and `Figure 2`. Is it possible to do ?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR, I hadn't understood you well. In that case I would use `minipage`s and the `caption` package. See the last edit.

Comment: That is what I wanted. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

> Any help both with the 2D and 3D graph of the given 3 inequalities.

The straight forward way would be to plot the 3 inequalites for z = 0 in 2D. Unfortunately I never worked with the package before, so I have to leave the code details to the experts.

However ..

> 0 <= x+y+1, 0 <= 4x, 0 <= 5y.
>
> The 2D projection is as follows (i.e., z=0-plane):

... are you sure the diagram matches these 3 inequalities?

- x >= 0
- y >= 0
- x + y >= -1

Comment: Yes. Good point. I removed the 2D picture. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: I think, my 2D projection was correct. For example if you match the 2D projection in my question with the answer of @Juan  in xy-plane.