# Side-by-side pictures on a landscape page

Tags: floats, landscape, includegraphics

How to fit two pictures side-by-side on a landscape page?

(**EDIT:** I have answered this Q&A style below. Other approaches or suggestions for improvement are welcomed)

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: below is the one that I got working, will edit the question.

Comment: What is wrong with your code fragment? It works fine (including it in some test document).

Comment: the idea was to answer my own question q&a style but will be more specific in the future.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

It is easy with the `subfloatrow` environment from package `floatrow`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow} 

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\floatsetup{captionskip=2ex}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \ffigbox[\textheight]{%
  \begin{subfloatrow}[2]
      \centering
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Ils se lèvent à la pointe du jour (1950)}\label{T1}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{PointeduJour}}
        \qquad
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{La Dormeuse (1937)}\label{T2}}{\includegraphics[scale=1.37]{LaDormeuse}}
    \end{subfloatrow}%
    }{\caption{Two Paintings by Toyen}\label{Toyen}}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what is your problem. Your code fragment inserted in some test document, for example as is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
% your code fragment
\end{document}
```

works fine and it has today recommended form. Of course, you can make it a wee bit shorter by use of `Gin` keywords as I do in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[p]
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}  % <---
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\caption{Caption 1}
\label{fig:subim1}
  \end{subfigure}
\hfil      
   \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\caption{Caption 2}
\label{fig:subim2}
  \end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption for this figure with two images: by use of \texttt{subfigure} (recommended)}
\label{fig:image2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[p]
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.45\linewidth}  % <---
  \centering
  \subfloat[Caption 1   \label{fig:subim1}]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
\hfil
  \subfloat[Caption 2   \label{fig:subim2}]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
 
\caption{Caption for this figure with two images: by use of \texttt{subfloat} (less recommended)} 
\label{fig:image2}
\end{figure}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Beside above solutions exist other too. See [@Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/612112/side-by-side-pictures-on-a-landscape-page/612121#612121) answer (+1).