# Overlapping curves/planes in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I make the planes show up as surfaces where the ones on the front overlaps the ones on the back. I want to go from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-4,xmax=4,ymin=-4,ymax=4,zmin=-4,zmax=4]
\addplot3[gray,surf]{x};
\addplot3[gray,surf]{-x+2};
\addplot3[gray,surf]{5*x+5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This post is similar, but the answer is made in plain Ti*k*Z (easier and better-looking IMHO): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604334/how-to-plot-the-3d-graph-of-the-following-three-inequalities-in-latex-e-g-tik

Comment: You could restrict the planes using `domain` and stack the resulting parts in a specific way.

Comment: There is also this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294371/47927