# Can't get this caption right (wrapfig + floatrow)

Tags: captions, wrapfigure, floatrow

I'm trying to get a caption to span the figure width on a wrapfig environment. But for some reasons it just won't go. Here is my code and a graphical representation:

[image: problem]

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.3\textwidth}    
  \vspace{-30pt}
  \label{fig:UbiContentClass}
  \ffigbox[\textwidth]
  {
    \caption{A classe que define Conteúdo Ubíquo}
  }
  {
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/UbiContentClass.png}
  }
  \vspace{-20pt}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Comment: Please add to your question a *complete* and *minimal* version of the code illustrating the problem.

Comment: ...this will just make things easier for others to help you. Change your `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...}` into `\rule{\textwidth}{...}` and include at least `floatrow` and `wrapfig`. *Don't* use the `minimal` document class, but `article` rather.

Comment: @Werner I don't get it - you're saying to replace 'includegraphics' with 'rule'? I tried this but it doesn't build: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
{
  \caption{caption text caption text caption text caption text 
  caption text caption text caption text caption text 
  caption text caption text caption text caption text }\label{...}
}
{
  %\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{dummy}
\rule{.4\linewidth]{dummy}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

Comment: @DavidDoria: The motivation is that we don't have the OP's `figs/UbiContentClass.png`. An alternative would be to use image from the [`mwe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe) so that everyone can replicate the problem without having to worry about missing images. `\rule{<width>}{<height>}` is how you should use it to create a black box of width `<width>` and height `<height>`. If you `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`, then all images will appear in 100mmx150mm black boxes, but that may not be the size of the original graphic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\ffigbox[\FBwidth]` instead of `\ffigbox[\textwidth]`. This will equal the caption width to that of object. Here is a screen shot from `floatrow` documentation for more details.

[image]

The MWE for your case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % Remove demo in your file
\usepackage{wrapfig,floatrow}
\usepackage{lipsum} % provides dummy text
%------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.3\textwidth}
%\vspace{-30pt} % why this space?
  \label{fig:UbiContentClass}
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
  {
    \caption{A classe que define Conteúdo Ubíquo}
  }
  {
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/UbiContentClass.png}
  }
%\vspace{-20pt} % why this space?
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2-3]    
%------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The space is to remove the extra empty stuff.

Comment: @Harish Kumar I tried this (without the wrapfigure) and it lets the caption be much wider than the image: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
{
  \caption{caption text caption text caption text caption text 
  caption text caption text caption text caption text 
  caption text caption text caption text caption text }\label{...}
}
{
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{dummy}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

Comment: @DavidDoria You have to use `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}`. note `\linewidth` instead of `0.4\linewidth`.

Comment: @HarishKumar but then the image is also linewidth. I want to size my image to my liking, then have the text aligned to its edges below it.

Comment: @DavidDoria If you use `0.4\linewidth` natually image will be smaller as the caption will span `\linewidth`.

Comment: @HarishKumar So that is the question - how to get the caption to span only the figure width, whatever it may be?

Comment: @DavidDoria Change `\ffigbox[0.2\FBwidth]`. Change accordingly.

Comment: @HarishKumar I don't understand what this is doing. According to the floatrow doc, "But if you set, for example, the option [\FBwidth] like below, you’ll get a caption width equal to the width of picture". With \ffigbox[\FBwidth] and \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{dummy}, the caption is much bigger than the figure. If I make it \ffigbox[.5\FBwidth] to match, then the figure gets even smaller, and the caption is still bigger than the figure. What is the relationship between these two width settings?

Comment: @DavidDoria `\FBwidth` equals the natural width of the float contents. ie, here `\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.3\textwidth}`. But includegraphics has a width of `.4\linewidth`, ie, 0.4 times the width of `0.3\textwidth`. For details on line width and `\textwidth` see [Difference between \textwidth, \linewidth and \hsize](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16942).

Comment: @HarishKumar I'm sorry, so I still don't understand then how I would make the caption the same width as the figure?