# How do I typeset a table with a caption within a tabularx within another table with a caption?

Tags: tables, captions, tabularx

Unfortunately, it keeps bugging me with `forgotten \endgroup`, `float(s) lost`, `not in outer par mode` and so on.

In other words, why can't I do something like this (the actual table is significantly more complex with rules and stuff):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}
    \begin{table}
      \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}
        \blindtext
      \end{tabularx}
      \caption{Inner table}
    \end{table}
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Outer table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would also love to have a tabularx inside the inner table.

Comment: How should the inner table be enumerated (in relation to the outer one)?

Comment: Hmm, a good question. I guess I'd like to go with no enumeration for the inner table. I'd be extremely grateful for any other option though, as I'm really tired of trying to accomplish this.

Comment: @EgorTensin Don’t use the inner `table` environment (how should floating work inside a `tabularx` anyway?) and drop the inner `\caption` (no enumeration) command.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, but I would like to have a caption, It's just the number that's useless. Or maybe you're suggesting just centering a paragraph as a caption?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. Nested `table` environments: `Not in outer par mode`

   I suggest dropping the inner `table` environment. (How should the concept of floating be applicable inside a tabular where the contents are fixed, anyway?)
2. Nested `tabularx` environments:

   - `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup`,
   - `Missing \endgroup inserted` and
   - `Missing } inserted`

   The solution is to enclose the inner `tabularx` by a pair of braces.
   The the [`tabularx` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tools/tabularx.pdf) states:

   > `tabular` and `tabular*` environments may be nested with no restriction,
   >   however if one `tabularx` environment occurs inside another, then the inner
   >   one must be enclosed by `{ }`.

Now the inner caption does work without problems and results in a enumerated caption:

> Table 1: Inner table

If this is not preferred, one can use the starred version of `\caption*` for the inner caption from the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package.

---

I also replaced `\textwidth` with `\linewidth` so that inner `tabularx` uses the correct remaining horizontal space (→ [Difference between \textwidth, \linewidth and \hsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16942/16595))

*Further improvements*  could be

- enclosing the inner `tabularx` and its `caption` inside the `center` environment or
- providing more vertical space before the inner `tabularx`, i.e. `\\[2ex]`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X}
     \blindtext \\
      {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X}
        \blindtext
      \end{tabularx}}
      \caption{Inner table}
     \\
     \blindtext
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Outer table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I thought the rule was one caption per one table. Seriously, how dumb am I?