# Fit table in page column also some editing

Tags: tables, two-column, tabularx

I want to make the table fit into one column in a two column page.

Also, I need it to look like this:

[image]

Here’s my code

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\adjustbox{max height=\dimexpr\textheight-3cm\relax,
           max width=0.4\textwidth}{
\begin{tabular}{|rr|rrrrrrrr|}
\hline
           &            &            &            &            &     Wrist  &            &            &            &            \\

           &            &    {\bf 1} &     {\bf } &    {\bf 2} &     {\bf } &    {\bf 3} &     {\bf } &    {\bf 4} &     {\bf } \\
\hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{Upper Arm} & \multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{Lower Arm} & \multicolumn{ 2}{|c}{Wrist Twist} & \multicolumn{ 2}{|c}{Wrist Twist} & \multicolumn{ 2}{|c}{Wrist Twist} & \multicolumn{ 2}{|c|}{Wrist Twist} \\

\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} &          1 &          2 &          1 &          2 &          1 &          2 &          1 &          2 \\
\hline
           &          1 &          1 &          2 &          2 &          2 &          2 &          3 &          3 &          3 \\

         1 &          2 &          2 &          2 &          2 &          2 &          3 &          3 &          3 &          3 \\

           &          3 &          2 &          3 &          3 &          3 &          3 &          3 &          4 &          4 \\
\hline
           &          1 &          2 &          3 &          3 &          3 &          3 &          4 &          4 &          4 \\

         2 &          2 &          3 &          3 &          3 &          3 &          3 &          4 &          4 &          4 \\

           &          3 &          3 &          4 &          4 &          4 &          4 &          4 &          5 &          5 \\
\hline
           &          1 &          3 &          3 &          4 &          4 &          4 &          4 &          5 &          5 \\

         3 &          2 &          3 &          4 &          4 &          4 &          4 &          4 &          5 &          5 \\

           &          3 &          4 &          4 &          4 &          4 &          4 &          5 &          5 &          5 \\
\hline
           &          1 &          4 &          4 &          4 &          4 &          4 &          5 &          5 &          5 \\

         4 &          2 &          4 &          4 &          4 &          4 &          4 &          5 &          5 &          5 \\

           &          3 &          4 &          4 &          4 &          5 &          5 &          5 &          6 &          6 \\
\hline
           &          1 &          5 &          5 &          5 &          5 &          5 &          6 &          6 &          7 \\

         5 &          2 &          5 &          6 &          6 &          6 &          6 &          6 &          7 &          7 \\

           &          3 &          6 &          6 &          6 &          7 &          7 &          7 &          7 &          8 \\
\hline
           &          1 &          7 &          7 &          7 &          7 &          7 &          8 &          8 &          9 \\

         6 &          2 &          8 &          8 &          8 &          8 &          8 &          9 &          9 &          9 \\

           &          3 &          9 &          9 &          9 &          9 &          9 &          9 &          9 &          9 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Wrist and arms scores table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which results in

[image]

Can you please make me this 2 tables [1st table](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6hyp5eotfcisskv/Screen%20Shot%202013-03-12%20at%207.33.43%20PM.png) [2nd table](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o8wy8jcguatj7a8/Screen%20Shot%202013-03-12%20at%207.33.31%20PM.png)also as I need them urgently? Many Thanks for your kind consideration and assistance, I really appreciate it

12%20at%207.26.10%20PM.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tabularx` package is good to fit a tabular to a specified width. Here it’s the current `\linewidth` (→ [Difference between \textwidth, \linewidth and \hsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16942)).

I guessed that the two most left columns should be twice as wide as the other ones. According to this I have set `\hsize`. (The sum of all `\hsize` still have to be the number of `X` columns.)

I have also reduced the horizontal space between columns:

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{.3\tabcolsep}
```

With the `\cline{2-10}` you can specify a `\hline` that only goes from the second to the tenth column.

### Code

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{F}{>{\bfseries}c}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\centering\setlength{\tabcolsep}{.3\tabcolsep}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*2{>{\centering\hsize=1.6666\hsize}X|}*8{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=.83333\hsize}X|}}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{8}{F|}{Wrist}                                                                                        \\
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{F}{1}      & \multicolumn{2}{F}{2}      & \multicolumn{2}{F}{3}      & \multicolumn{2}{F|}{4}     \\ \hline
    Upper & Lower        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Twist} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Twist} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Twist} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Twist} \\
    Arm   & Arm          & 1 & 2                      & 1 & 2                      & 1 & 2                      & 1 & 2                      \\ \hline
          & 1            & 1 & 2                      & 2 & 2                      & 2 & 3                      & 3 & 3                      \\ \cline{2-10}
    1     & 2            & 2 & 2                      & 2 & 2                      & 3 & 3                      & 3 & 3                      \\ \cline{2-10}
          & 3            & 2 & 3                      & 3 & 3                      & 3 & 3                      & 4 & 4                      \\ \hline
          & 1            & 2 & 3                      & 3 & 3                      & 3 & 4                      & 4 & 4                      \\
    2     & 2            & 3 & 3                      & 3 & 3                      & 3 & 4                      & 4 & 4                      \\
          & 3            & 3 & 4                      & 4 & 4                      & 4 & 4                      & 5 & 5                      \\ \hline
          & 1            & 3 & 3                      & 4 & 4                      & 4 & 4                      & 5 & 5                      \\
    3     & 2            & 3 & 4                      & 4 & 4                      & 4 & 4                      & 5 & 5                      \\
          & 3            & 4 & 4                      & 4 & 4                      & 4 & 5                      & 5 & 5                      \\ \hline
          & 1            & 4 & 4                      & 4 & 4                      & 4 & 5                      & 5 & 5                      \\
    4     & 2            & 4 & 4                      & 4 & 4                      & 4 & 5                      & 5 & 5                      \\
          & 3            & 4 & 4                      & 4 & 5                      & 5 & 5                      & 6 & 6                      \\ \hline
          & 1            & 5 & 5                      & 5 & 5                      & 5 & 6                      & 6 & 7                      \\
    5     & 2            & 5 & 6                      & 6 & 6                      & 6 & 6                      & 7 & 7                      \\
          & 3            & 6 & 6                      & 6 & 7                      & 7 & 7                      & 7 & 8                      \\ \hline
          & 1            & 7 & 7                      & 7 & 7                      & 7 & 8                      & 8 & 9                      \\
    6     & 2            & 8 & 8                      & 8 & 8                      & 8 & 9                      & 9 & 9                      \\
          & 3            & 9 & 9                      & 9 & 9                      & 9 & 9                      & 9 & 9                      \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Wrist and arms scores table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: The `tabularx` documentation states: “Do not use `\multicolumn` entries which cross any `X` column.” Huh …

Comment: can this be done? As I need it urgently please? https://www.dropbox.com/s/you1jfe9qmj01wa/RULAv04%20Revised.xls ???

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Following the rules ensures nothing bad happens and tabularx always converges to a more or less reasonable width, if you break the rules then usually you are OK, but documenting exactly when things might go wrong is too hard.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your late comment. I guess, I am going to cross my fingers when working with tables …