# Picture not formatting to text width

Tags: graphics, margins, warnings

I'm trying to format a picture so that it fills the text width however it always errors and fills the whole page.

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{circle}
```

is the line I'm currently using also this is probably relevent

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,reprint,nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Also this is the error I'm getting:

```
Overfull \hbox (264.0pt too wide) in paragraph
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: @JonathanWebb `Overfull \hbox (264.0pt too wide)` is not an error. It is a warning. Also, please always provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: If you want that the image fills the column width, use `\columnwidth` and not `\textwidth` that encompasses the two columns. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16956/4427 for more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to fill the column, not the page; so the correct parameter to use is `\columnwidth`

```
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{circle}
```

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16956/4427 for more information.