# Vertical alignment within table with graphics

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Perhaps I am doing it the wrong way, but I have a `table` with 3 `tabulars` arranged within `minipage` each, such that I end up with 3 tables side by side. Each table only has 2 columns: 1 for text and one has `includegraphics`. I am trying to vertically align text in the first column to be in the middle of the cell.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabu, lscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[!t]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\linewidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    Col1 & Col2 \\
    Text & \includegraphics{<path>} \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\linewidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    Col1 & Col2 \\
    Text & \includegraphics{<path>} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\linewidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    Col1 & Col2 \\
    Text & \includegraphics{<path>} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried using `m{'width'}` from the `array` package but no luck. I was wondering if anyone had a suggestion how to achieve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the `subcaption` package and its `subtable` command: http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand your question correctly, but to me the cells get centered when using `m{width}` as column definition (from the `array` package), as you suggested.

Here is the code I used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabu, lscape, array}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[!t]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}C{1.5cm}@{}C{3.5cm}@{}}
    Col1 & Col2 \\
    Text & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{<path>} \\ 
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}C{1.5cm}@{}C{3.5cm}@{}}
    Col1 & Col2 \\
    Text & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{<path>} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hspace*{1.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}C{1.5cm}@{}C{3.5cm}@{}}
    Col1 & Col2 \\
    Text & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{<path>} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

and here is the output:

[image: Output]

If you want to also center the columns horizontally, you will need to define a new `C` column type as such:

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
```

and replace `m` by `C` in the column definitions of the `tabular`s of the code above. The result is then:

[image: Result with columns also centered horizontally]

Two last note:
 - I've replaced the references to `\columnwidth` in the width of the column definitions by set values. References to `\columnwidth` would not be appropriate nor working / constant here (see [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16956/10102) to [Difference between \textwidth, \linewidth and \hsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16942/10102) to understand why).
 - In your code, the `minipages` are not necessary at all.

Comment: This is most excellent! But I only have 1 question is there a way to keep column headings in aligned to center?

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how to do this with `\newcolumntype`.