# Two subfigures in two rows

Tags: subfloats

I would like to have two subfigures but on two rows. I tried with this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{report}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{subcaption}  

\begin{document}  

\begin{figure}[h!]  
\centering  
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}  
  \centering  
  \includegraphics[width=1.8\linewidth]{image}  
    \caption{Caption for image 1}   
\end{subfigure}   

\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}  
  \centering  
  \includegraphics[width=1.8\linewidth]{image}  
    \caption{Caption for image 2}   
\end{subfigure}  
\caption{A caption for both images}  
\end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

The result is: both figures are aligned to the right side of the page while the caption of each figure is still in the center.
Really appreciate if some one could help me!

Edit: Image of the result if this could help
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `1.8\linewidth` is 80% too wide for the current block (which is `.5\textwidth` wide), causing a problem. Try using only `\linewidth` or at least some portion of it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption for image 1}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Caption for image 2}
  \end{subfigure}  
  \caption{A caption for both images}  
\end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

Remember that `\linewidth` is a relative length. See [Difference between `\textwidth`, `\linewidth` and `\hsize`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16942/5764).

Comment: I see! But the reason why I set that number so high because my figures are way too small. Do you have any suggestion how I can increase the size of the figures without causing the problem?

Comment: @atn: You can scale them as I did. If you use `\linewidth` for the `subfigure` environment width, then the block containing the subfigure will be as wide as the text block. Then, relative to that `width=.8\linewidth` will scale the image to be 80% of the text block (enlarge/shrink).

Comment: @atn - Have you tried setting `0.9\textwidth` (=0.5*1.8) or just `\textwidth` for the width of the `subfigure` environments?

Comment: Thank you both, Werner and Mico. I reduced `1.8\linewidth` to something like `0.99\linewidth`, then changed my old `.5\textwidth` for the `subfigure` environment to either `\linewidth` (as Werner said) or `.9\textwidth` (as Mico suggested). Both way work for me.