# Automatically set the figure width depending on whether the layout is one or two column

Tags: tables, floats, two-column, width

I am wondering how do you usually deal with figure width when you are writing a paper. (use `\linewidth`, `\textwidth` ? others?)

Maybe we can just define a "switch" and use it with `ifelse` package?

(Assume that you are writing a `onecolumn` version, and you also want to know the `twocolumn` layout at the same time without adjusting the `\witdh` manually too often.)

**EDIT**. LaTeX is quite "intelligent" to format the text content. Can we let it deal with figures the same way?

That is, when we add a figure, we not only just set the `width=...`, but also add a tag for informing LaTeX that "I am setting this `width` according to `A4` paper `twocolumn`".

Then when we change the layout to `onecolumn`, LaTeX knows how to handle (rescale).

**EDIT**

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{figColumnTrueOneFalseTwo}
\setboolean{figColumnTrueOneFalseTwo}{false}
%\setboolean{figColumnTrueOneFalseTwo}{true}

% in main.tex
\ifthenelse {\boolean{figColumnTrueOneFalseTwo}}{
% for onecolumn here
}{
% for twocolumn here
}
```

Comment: Is `\columnwidth` what you are looking for?

Comment: @karlkoeller Oh, I've never used `\columnwidth`, +1. Thanks! (I am looking for suggestions, and would like to know how people usually do! :))

Comment: `\columnwidth` or `\linewidth` should do what you want.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/difference-between-textwidth-linewidth-and-hsize

Comment: Can you expalin the edit a bit better? Wasn't `\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{...}` enough? What do you need this info for?

Comment: @karlkoeller, from `\documentclass[twocolumn]{IEEEtran}` to `\documentclass[onecolumn]{IEEEtran}`, the image width would be doubled if we use `\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]`. Maybe `\textwidth` is a better choice, but when `subfig` package is also used, we have to add linebreak `\\ ` when switching to `twocolumn`.

Comment: I don't understand. `\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{..}` is the answer?

Answer (score 5):

As this question was solved in the comments, in order to remove from  *unanswered*, this is a *community wiki* answer.

Sort answer: usually `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}` automatically fit well in most cases.

Long answer:

[Difference between \textwidth, \linewidth and \hsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/difference-between-textwidth-linewidth-and-hsize) (and `\columnwidth`) is well 
explained in the above link. In practice, in one column document, `\textwidth`,`\columnwidth` and `\linewidth` is the same length (while you are out of any special environment), so you can use any of these lengths to fix the width of the image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin {document} 
\the\textwidth   % this length is 345.0pt
\the\linewidth   % this is  also  345.0pt
\the\columnwidth % this is again  345.0pt
\end{document}
```

However, if you change from one to two column, then `\textwidth` is more than twice the width of one column and largely inappropiate for the figures that must fit within  one column:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\begin {document} 
\the\textwidth   % this is now 469.0pt
\the\linewidth   % this is now 229.5pt
\the\columnwidth % this is now 229.5pt
\end{document}
```

So, one may think that, that as general rule, is  safer  `\columnwidth`, since this work in both formats. Nonetheless, in two columns documents are usual the figures extending in two columns (starred floats `\begin{figure*} ...`) where (one) `\columnwidth` is just the wrong option. Instead, `\linewidth` fill the space as expected in both starred and not starred floats, as well as in images without floats, in both one or two columns documents.

For images without floats and inside in some environment is not possible a general rule, but probably `\linewidth` is the choice in most cases. For example, in a `itemize` environment will be 20pt narrower that the column width, that probably is what you want for an "itemized" picture (...or may be not, it depend of what you want).