# How to fit a table of figures with various sizes into a page

Tags: tables, floats, fit

I'm trying to fit four figures with various sizes into a table on one page. I started with the following code, but couldn't figure out how to get it work. How can I achieve that?

```
begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{fig1.jpg} &
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{fig2.jpg} \\
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{fig3.pdf} & 
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{fig4.pdf} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: `\textwidth` is the full width of text on the page, use something smaller such as `0.4\textwidth`.  Similaryl for `\textheight`.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: Yes, playing with those numbers (scalers?0 worked! Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides reducing `\textwidth` to some less than 50%, in general it could be better change this length to `\linewidth`. Many times is exactly the same length, but when this is not true, probably what you want really is \linewidth, not `\textwidth` nor `\columnwidth`. See [Automatically set the figure width depending on whether the layout is one or two column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131231/automatically-set-the-figure-width-depending-on-whether-the-layout-is-one-or-two).

To reduce typing of repeated code in the next example I used a rudimentary macro, I hope this will be not confusing. It show two floats, with and without subcaptions, where using `\linewidth` does matter even in documents with only one column.

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove "demo" to use with your images
\usepackage{subcaption}

% macro only to simplify floats code 
% now  \linewidth  = \textwidth 

\newcommand\myfig[1]{%
\includegraphics[width=.49\linewidth,height=.2\textheight,keepaspectratio]{#1}}

\begin{document}

% simple example without subcaptions
\begin{figure}
\centering
\myfig{fig1.jpg}\hfill\myfig{fig2.jpg}\\[1ex]
\myfig{fig3.dpf}\hfill\myfig{fig4.dpf}\\
\caption{Four images}
\end{figure}


% example with subcaptions

\renewcommand\myfig[1]{%
\includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth,height=.5\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{#1}}

% Note that now the image width will be the  95% of the
% subfigure line width, that is less than the 48% of the 
% line width (= text width) of the main text.    

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\myfig{fig1.jpg}
\caption{fig1}%
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\myfig{fig2.jpg}
\caption{fig2}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\myfig{fig3.pdf}
\caption{fig3}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\myfig{fig4.pdf}
\caption{fig4}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Four images again}

\end{figure}


\end{document}
```