# Images added with graphicx never stays where I put them

Tags: graphics, positioning

I've tried this in different occasions within the past year and I have always had the same problem. I go to the line of the Latex code where I want to insert my images using `\begin{figure}`, but the images appear before the content in the previous lines:

```
\lstinputlisting{q9_1_c.m}


\vspace*{5\baselineskip}

\begin{figure}[!tbp]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{diff_6}
    \caption{$\nu = 6$.}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{diff_7}
    \caption{$\nu = 7$}
 \end{minipage}
   \hfill
 \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{diff_8}
\caption{$\nu = 8$}
 \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

produces a layout in which the images precede the code included using `\lstinputlisting{}`. This is not an issue if I just use `\includegraphics`, but I needed to put 3 images next to each other. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Because `figure` is an environment which tells LaTeX to 'float' the contents to the best location, where the best location is determined by LaTeX's algorithm. You can put the graphics next to one another without using a `figure environment`. Just don't put paragraph breaks between them.

Comment: Thanks! How can I also include captions without using the `figure environment`?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/label-and-caption-without-float.

Comment: Your figure go to the top of the page because you are using the **`t`** op option in  `figure`. Change `[!tpb]` by  just `[bp]` or `[hbp]`. BTW, `\centering` is superfluous here. BTW, may be you are searching for one figure with three subfigures? In this case use the `subfig` or `subcaption` packages instead of minipages.

Comment: BTW, it is safer user `\linewidth` that `\textwidth`. See what happen with this figure if you add `twocolumn` options to the document class, or if the figure is part of of a item in a list, for example. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142709/11604

Comment: The reason that typesetting systems move figures (and figures have referencable captions) is to avoid bad page breaks. If you do not float the figures you will get large spaces at page breaks, and really captions are not required as the image is then just part of the text flow (like an equation which similarly does not float, and is typically not captioned)

Comment: The previously referenced solution is far more complicated than needed.  Just use \captionof{figure}{yada yada yada} anywhere.  It will then show up in the list of figures as well.