# making included graphics larger

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to include some graphics into my `report`, and I can't find the normal width which can take an image to respect the margin-left and the margin-right of a page.

Here is the code that I've tried :

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\hfill{}\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{images/seq_auth}\hfill{}
\caption{abc}
\label{fg:seq_auth}
\end{figure}
```

But, the font of the text that is part of the graphic is too small to see when I've printed it. So, I thought that I maybe need to make it as wide as possible.

Any suggestions, please ?

Comment: `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/seq_auth}` only. Remove both `\hfill{}` and use `\centering` inside the `figure` environment.

Comment: See [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131231/automatically-set-the-figure-width-depending-on-whether-the-layout-is-one-or-two) related question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document} 

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/seq_auth}
\caption{abc}
\label{fg:seq_auth}
\end{figure}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or even \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{...} or such.